# ¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?

Tags: soporte, faq, reputación, votos, voto-serial

Adaptación de la pregunta [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/182862)

---

Acabo de ver que he perdido varios puntos de reputación en mi cuenta en StackOverflow en español. Fui a mi perfil, a la pestaña "reputación" para intentar rastrear la causa.

Durante mi investigación, pude notar que hubo un evento inusual de tipo "reversión". En el lugar normal del título de la pregunta, me aparecía "Votación corregida".

[image: Ayer, perdí 172 puntos de reputación donde dice "Votación corregida"]

- ¿Qué significa y qué lo causó?
- ¿Hice algo malo?
- ¿Por qué perdí toda esa reputación? ¿Acaso el sistema me está castigando por dejar muchas respuestas buenas?
- ¿Hay alguna manera de recuperar los puntos?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Respuesta adaptada de https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/182862

---

### ¿Qué es el fraude de votos?

El fraude de votos consiste en los votos sistemáticos contra los votos racionales. El fraude suele suceder cuando un usuario vota continuamente (a favor o en contra) en muchas de tus publicaciones en un corto periodo de tiempo. Esto no se considera comportamiento normal y el sistema no lo permitirá.

Si los votos masivos continúan pasando entre dos direcciones IP particulares (votando a favor entre ellas) o desde un único usuario, o simplemente luce sospechoso, los moderadores y/o desarrolladores pueden investigar el caso y aplicar acciones disciplinarias contra los usuarios envueltos en el fraude.

### ¿Cuándo ocurre el *voto serial a favor*?

A menudo cuando obtienes mucha reputación inesperadamente, lo creas o no, solo es un usuario intentando darte reputación adicional. Ellos vieron una publicación tuya que fue extraordinariamente de ayuda para ellos y sintieron que debían ir por varias publicaciones tuyas y votarlas a favor en forma de agradecimiento al brindarte más reputación (aparentemente se olvidaron del [sistema de recompensas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)).

Ocasionalmente, también ocurre entre dos usuarios que han hecho un acuerdo de darse votos a favor mutuamente, o entre un usuario y una cuenta falsa, intentando jugar en el sistema por reputación adicional (lo cual usualmente llevará a la suspensión).

### ¿Cuándo ocurre el *voto serial en contra*?

Usualmente, cuando ocurre el voto serial en contra es porque un usuario  no está de acuerdo con lo que otro usuario ha publicado, ya sea una respuesta o un comentario. El usuario visita el perfil del usuario afectado y, similar al voto serial a favor, visita sistemáticamente sus publicaciones (usualmente preguntas) y las vota en contra. Ocasionalmente, pueden haber otras razones, como jugarle una broma.

### ¿Qué hacer si pienso que soy víctima de un fraude de votos?

Si el fraude de votos está en progreso o ha sucedido recientemente, no te preocupes. Antes de preocuparte, debes esperar al menos 24 horas luego de enterarte del fraude. El sistema debería detectarlo y revertirlo por ti. Por favor **no** intentes obtener ayuda sobre este tema en meta o poniendo una bandera para moderación. Todo lo que ellos (los moderadores) harán es esperar que se ejecute el script de fraude de votos (ellos no lo ejecutarán por ti).

Si han pasado las 24 horas y los votos sospechosos no han sido revertidos, entonces puedes poner una bandera en una de tus publicaciones y explicar lo que sucede, así un moderador va a revisar el tema. Usualmente se prefiere que *evites* preguntar sobre esto en los sitios Meta porque los detalles de la investigación no se pueden divulgar y porque no obtendrías información que será útil a otros miembros de la comunidad.

### ¿Cómo es que el sistema detecta el fraude de votos?

Todas las noches, alrededor de las 03:00 UTC, se ejecuta un script de detección de fraude de votos que busca por patrones como estos. Básicamente, busca por usuarios que han votado a favor a otro usuario muchas veces. El número es justamente bajo dentro de un periodo de tiempo dado (el funcionamiento exacto se mantiene en secreto). Cuando el sistema detecta este patrón, todos los votos hechos de ese usuario al usuario afectado son revertidos y se imprime el enunciado "Votación corregida" en el historial de reputación del usuario afectado para indicar lo que ha ocurrido.

El valor de la reversión puede ser cualquiera, puesto que es la combinación de todos los votos siendo revertidos (a favor y en contra, aunque la mayoría de votos seriales ocurren en una dirección). Si has alcanzado el límite de reputación (del día), el valor se puede mostrar en blanco si ninguno de los votos revertidos afectaron la reputación de ese día.

### ¿El sistema detecta el fraude de votos en publicaciones eliminadas?

Sí. Si votas serialmente en publicaciones y luego una o más de ellas son eliminadas luego, el script revertirá esos votos, si es que los detecta.

Un usuario regular puede darse cuenta de esta "característica" cuando se encuentra con un spam, revisa la cuenta del spammer, luego descubre y vota en contra una serie de "respuesta" que tienen el mismo contenido spam. Incluso si todas las publicaciones tienen una bandera y luego se eliminan, al cabo de un tiempo se puede encontrar una seria de entradas de **+1 eliminación de voto** en su historial de reputación marcados con la fecha en que el script de reversa de votos se ejecutó. ([Ejemplo (del sitio en inglés)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7493744#7493744)).

### ¿Por qué no puedo mantener la reputación?

La reputación fue removida porque no es comportamiento apropiado y no está permitido. Los votos fueron invalidados por completo por el sistema y así la reputación ganada de ellos fue invalidada. La única manera que puedes obtener esta reputación de vuelta es crear más publicaciones y obtener votos a favor de manera legítima de estas publicaciones.

### ¿Debería preocuparme sobre los enunciados de reversa en mi perfil?

No, para nada. Solo indica un cambio de reputación. Después de todo, nosotros no podemos controlar las acciones de otros usuarios. Es muy raro donde nos hemos encontrado con un usuario que haya cometido fraude de votos en su propia cuenta, y en muchos casos, ellos ya habrían sido tratados apropiadamente. De ninguna manera, no deberías preocuparte de los enunciados de reversa en tu historial de reputación.

### ¿Qué más debería saber sobre este tema?

- **Las reversas disparan un recálculo de la reputación.**

  Cuando el voto serial se revierte, todos los días involucrados en el voto serial serán recalculados como si el voto serial nunca hubiese sucedido, cualquier reputación que hayas perdido debido a esos votos seriales que te hagan alcanzar el límite de reputación te será devuelto en ese día. Los votantes seriales no prevendrán que ganes la reputaciǿn que te mereces.
- **Los votos pueden ser re-emitidos.**

  Los votos revertidos por el script de detección pueden ser re-emitidos por el usuario luego de un tiempo, siempre y cuando el usuario no vuelva a caer en voto serial, lo que causaría que los votos sean revertidos (una vez más).
- **No existe un castigo automático ni notificaciones.**

  Actualmente, las reversas de voto serial *solo* revierten los votos. Puedes ver lo que sucedió al mirar tu historial de reputación, pero es lo máximo que este script hace. No existe una suspensión para los usuarios que participen en votos seriales, y la única notificación que ellos reciben es que sus votos fueron revertidos como un evento en su historial de reputación si han tenido respuestas votadas en contra (si ellos solo votaron preguntas o solo han votado a favor, no recibirán una notificación de ninguna forma).

  El abuso continuo del sistema que causa reversas múltiples pueden llevar a una suspensión, pero el proceso de revisión de suspensión es completamente manual. No existen banderas automáticas de este comportamiento, pero los moderadores tienen acceso a algunas estadísticas que ayudan a luchar contra los victimarios recurrentes. Si encuentras que eres víctima de voto serial en ocasiones múltiples dentro de un corto periodo de tiempo, siéntete libre de poner una bandera a una de tus publicaciones para la atención de un moderador y explicar la situación, así ellos podrán investigar más al respecto.