# Votaciones que atentan contra la comunidad

Tags: discusión, respuesta, votos, votos-negativos

Vengo a dar a conocer a la comunidad de stack**overflow** en español, un hecho que ocurrió con la siguiente pregunta:

[C++ Problema al imprimir matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/26307/10998)

Mi respuesta a la misma, fue la siguiente:

[Mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26320/10998)

La cual tuvo dos votaciones negativas, y sendos comentarios:

> "¿ Traducirlo a c para lograr mayor eficiencia ? Para empezar no es
> cierto que C sea más eficiente que C++, tampoco menos: si no
> diferente. Para acabar, no se puede decir algo así y no argumentarlo.
> Además la pregunta está etiquetada como C++, aunque fuese cierto que
> fuera menos eficiente, la respuesta debería ser acorde a lo que pide
> el autor de la pregunta. – PaperBirdMaster el 6 oct. a las 7:14"
>
> "Coincido plenamente con lo expuesto por @PaperBirdMaster. Por cierto,
> ¿por eficiencia te refieres al consumo de memoria o a tiempo de
> ejecución? Se te ha olvidado comentarlo y es un detalle importante.
> C++ no tiene por qué ser más lento que C, lo que sucede es que C++
> realiza llamadas a funciones de forma implícita (por ejemplo llamar a
> constructores cuando se crean objetos) que si no se controlan pueden
> conllevar una merma importante de rendimiento... pero el mismo código
> compilado en C y en C++ da los mismos resultados salvo por pequeños
> cambios de optimización realizados por el compilador. – eferion el 6
> oct. a las 7:20"

A lo cual respondí:

> Se equivocaron al calificar negativamente mi respuesta. Tratar las
> ventajas de c sobre c++ desvía el tema de dar solución al problema de
> rotación de la matriz. @isalvinator ha publicado un enlace para que
> podamos ver las condiciones del ejercicio. Si bien él usó la etiqueta
> c++, al visitar el enlace, vemos que en el ejercicio no se especifica
> el lenguaje a utilizar, por eso sería aconsejable incluir la etiqueta
> c, entre otras...[continúa] – Aprendiendo.NET el 7 oct. a las 1:17
>
> [continuación]...Por todo lo expuesto anteriormente, ratifico que mi
> respuesta se ajusta estrictamente a la pregunta planteada,
> proporcionando una solución eficaz que cumple con gran parte de las
> condiciones impuestas, principalmente el problema central que es la
> rotación de la matriz; pero la editaré, espero que en breve, para
> satisfacer completamente el enunciado, explicando detalladamente la
> solución. En consecuencia, solicito tengan a bien anular las
> calificaciones negativas.[Fin]. – Aprendiendo.NET el 7 oct. a las 1:18

Como si eso fuera poco, alguien borró la respuesta del usuario @PaperBirdMaster, luego que yo reclamase que no solucionaba el problema de la rotación de la matriz.

Expresamente, en un comentario, le pedí a dicho usuario que edite la respuesta, porque no cumplía en dar solución a la pregunta.

Esa respuesta sí merecía una votación negativa, sin embargo decidí no hacerlo para incentivar a dicho usuario para que pueda lograr una solución, y que ésa sea otra alternativa para el usuario @isalvinator.

En caso contrario no quedaría más remedio que dar una votación negativa a esa respuesta, que no cumplía con la solicitud de la pregunta.

Pero alguien tuvo la mala acción de borrar esa respuesta, rompiendo el hilo de la conversación, y privando a la comunidad de un elemento fundamental para la evaluación del problema que estoy dándoles a conocer.

Las votaciones negativas que recibió mi respuesta, no corresponden.

Digo que no corresponden porque mi respuesta se ajusta estrictamente a la pregunta planteada por @isalvinator, y es la única que hasta el día de la fecha da una respuesta eficaz para resolver el problema, teniendo en cuenta el código planteado.

Por tal motivo, solicité la moderación, reportando los comentarios arriba citados, pero @Luiggi Mendoza respondió lo siguiente:

> "La pregunta es sobre C++, entonces lo mejor es **primero** responder a la
> pregunta con C++. Adicional a ello, se puede brindar código que lo
> resuelve en C. Cuando brindes respuestas, considera que no solo estás
> ayudando al OP sino a cualquier lector de cualquier parte del mundo
> que busca una respuesta para un problema o situación similar."

Me resultó increíble ese comentario, por tal motivo lo reporté y respondí de la siguiente manera:

> "@Luiggi Mendoza ¿te parece que mi respuesta no está en c++? entonces
> el códgio de la pregunta tampoco lo está. Reitero que el código de mi
> respuesta está acorde con lo que pide el usuario, proporcionando el
> mínimo de modificaciones para que quien pregunta pueda lograr una
> mejor comprensión del mismo. Adicionalmente podía proporcionar un
> código en c puro, gracias a que la pregunta se presta para ello. Pero
> quiero que quede claro que mi respuesta se ajusta estrictamente a la
> pregunta realizada por @isalvinator, motivo por el cual solicito
> tengan a bien tener en cuenta mi pedido anterior."

Me parece que el problema está claro: las votaciones fueron incorrectas, pero no se quiere reconocer. Desconozco el motivo.

Pienso que estas actitudes livianas, haciendo votaciones negativas sin la correcta evaluación de la pregunta y la respuesta, ponen en peligro la reputación de la comunidad, y resulta mucho más peligrosa cuando está avalada por un moderador.

Otro detalle importante es que al reclamar la incorrecta respuesta del moderador @Luiggi Mendoza, quien me contesta es él mismo, lo cual no comparto, porque debe ser otro moderador quien examine si éste ha cometido algún error, para dar más transparencia a la cuestión en curso. Es decir, un moderador no debería atender a reclamos de sus propios comentarios, sino que esa tarea debería realizarla otro moderador, o alguien que tenga más autoridad.

Es muy importante que los reclamos de los usuarios sean tomados en cuenta, con el respeto y la seriedad que todos y cada uno de los usuarios de la comunidad se merecen.

Otro detalle que quería comentarles es que, sospechosamente luego de haber realizado esos reclamos, he recibido otra votación negativa, pero en otra pregunta. El enlace a la misma es el siguiente:

[¿Cuál es el error? Hallar el porcentaje de pares, impares y ceros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24883/10998)

[Mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24900/10998)

Digo que es sospechoso, porque no hay motivos para descalificar esa respuesta que, además de dar una solución clara y eficaz, se explica en detalle el tema de los números pares e impares y cómo poder aprovechar una alternativa de bajo nivel con oeraciones bit a bit, ajustándose estrictamente a la pregunta.

Para ir finalizando, y siempre que corresponda, solicito tengan a bien considerar los siguientes reclamos:

- Que se anulen las votaciones negativas incorrectas.
- Que haya quita de puntos para los usuarios que votaron incorrectamente.
- Que se implemente un sistema de control para que los moderadores sean controlados por sus pares o por integrantes de más autoridad.
- Impedir que alguien pueda borrar una respuesta, cuando ésta tiene un comentario donde se solicita la mejora de la misma, ajustándose a lo que pide la pregunta, so pena de recibir calificaciones negativas.

Comment: El de la segunda fui yo, una disculpa, voté sin pensar mucho.

Comment: No aplica la etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva] pues no está enfocada en una característica en particular.

Answer (score 9):

No tengo problema alguno en comentar que soy el autor de uno de los votos negativos que recibió [la respuesta de Aprendiendo.NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26320/10998).

El motivo de mi negativo no es la respuesta en si, si no las justificaciones que se dan en la misma:

> Muestro un ejemplo partiendo del código de la pregunta, pero es posible mejorarlo usando **c**, que es más rápido que **c++**:

Y

> - Traducirlo a **c** para lograr mayor eficiencia.

Es falso que C sea más rápido que C++, también es falso que sea más lento; lo mismo puede decirse de la eficiencia.

Hay situaciones y contextos en que esas afirmaciones pueden ser falsas y otras en que pueden no serlo, pero como [Aprendiendo.NET](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10998/aprendiendo-net) no justifica dichas afirmaciones lo que su aportación provoca es desinformación, justo lo opuesto al objetivo del sitio.

Así pues **el negativo viene motivado por la desinformación que provocan sus injustificadas afirmaciones**, no por el código de la respuesta. Por lo tanto: tenemos una pregunta etiquetada como C++, con código C++ y que demanda una solución en C++ que ha sido respondida diciendo que C++ es la peor solución, alegando problemas de velocidad y eficiencia sin demostrarlo.

Afirma:

- Es más rápido y eficiente C respecto C++.

Y dicha afirmación requiere responder a estas preguntas:

- ¿Por qué?
- ¿Qué Benchmarks has usado?
- ¿Qué compiladores has usado?
- ¿En que plataforma(s) has comprobado los resultados?
- ¿Cómo has comparado los resultados?

Ninguna de las preguntas anteriores son respondidas pero se da la rapidez y eficiencia como motivo del cambio de lenguaje, incluso cuando el usuario de la pregunta no manifestó estar preocupado por la velocidad o la eficiencia, así que repito mi [último comentario](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46626/discussion-on-answer-by-aprendiendo-net-c-problema-al-imprimir-matrices) en la pregunta:

> El cambiar el lenguaje de la respuesta no responde la pregunta, y menos aún alegando unos motivos que ni son ciertos ni son relevantes en el contexto de la pregunta... por poner otro ejemplo: **¿debería ser válida una respuesta en JavaScript alegando que de esa manera podría funcionar en navegadores web?**

Y añado: Si el motivo para cambiar de C++ a C era la velocidad y la eficiencia ¿por qué no aportar entonces código en ensamblador?

---

> Como si eso fuera poco, alguien borró la respuesta del usuario @PaperBirdMaster, luego que yo reclamase que no solucionaba el problema de la rotación de la matriz.
>
> Expresamente, en un comentario, le pedí a dicho usuario que edite la respuesta, porque no cumplía en dar solución a la pregunta.
>
> Esa respuesta sí merecía una votación negativa, sin embargo decidí no hacerlo para incentivar a dicho usuario para que pueda lograr una solución, y que ésa sea otra alternativa para el usuario @isalvinator.
>
> En caso contrario no quedaría más remedio que dar una votación negativa a esa respuesta, que no cumplía con la solicitud de la pregunta.
>
> Pero alguien tuvo la mala acción de borrar esa respuesta, rompiendo el hilo de la conversación, y privando a la comunidad de un elemento fundamental para la evaluación del problema que estoy dándoles a conocer.

Yo mismo borré la respuesta, me di cuenta de lo errónea que era después de que [Aprendiendo.NET](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10998/aprendiendo-net) señalara que no había entendido la pregunta, al ver que no podía aportar una respuesta mejor a la ya realizada por [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26322/2742) (pese a que lo intenté) ni añadir nada que diera valor añadido a las respuestas ya existentes decidí borrar mi respuesta (mejor no responder que responder mal).

Aprecio mucho mi puntuación de SOes, pero ser castigado con negativos no es una maldición si no un incentivo para pensar dos veces antes de publicar, que nadie dude en votarme negativo si cree que lo merezco.

Comment: +1 me gusto mucho tu reflexión final y estoy de acuerdo.

Answer (score 7):

Vayamos por partes.

Comentas que:

> Como si eso fuera poco, alguien borró la respuesta del usuario @PaperBirdMaster, luego que yo reclamase que no solucionaba el problema de la rotación de la matriz.

La respuesta en concreto fue eliminada por el propio @PaperBirdMaster después de que tu mismo le comentaras que su respuesta fue incorrecta y él te contestó así:

> Tienes toda la razón; mi respuesta es incorrecta y nada te impide evaluarla negativamente ni moral ni objetivamente; cabe la posibilidad que mi adición a la cafeína haya tenido algo que ver con mi error, pero con o sin café en vena si he respondido mal: puedo ser votado negativamente, lo mismo que tú.

Asumió su error, eliminó su publicación y ahí quedó la cosa. Veo muy bien su actuación en este caso, yo hubiera realizado lo mismo. Cuándo respondo de manera incorrecta elimino mi respuesta y si soy capaz de arreglarla la recupero (algo que pueden hacer sin necesidad de intervención de un moderador).

También comentas que:

> Las votaciones negativas que recibió mi respuesta, no corresponden.

Eso es una opinión subjetiva de tu propia respuesta. Ahora mismo tienes 1 upvote (mío) y 2 downvotes (desconozco de quién, pues son confidenciales hasta para los moderadores). Cuándo vi tu respuesta me pareció bien trabajada, aunque no respondía exactamente lo que pedía el autor vi el trabajo que habías realizado, vi que estaba en -2 y decidí, con mi opinión subjetiva, dar un upvote por el trabajo realizado.

Además, en [esta pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335965/1468942) del SO en inglés comentan que los *work-arounds* aunque no respondan *directamente* a la pregunta del OP, son aceptables, por eso voté positivamente a tu respuesta. Pero repito, es una opinión subjetiva.

Me gustaría destacar además que para los downvotes:

- No se requiere explicación alguna.
- Todo el mundo es libre de votar como quiera sin tener que dar explicaciones.
- Sólo existe 1 caso en que los downvotes son "eliminados": Serial downvoting, cuándo un mismo usuario vota negativamente en un corto plazo de tiempo a varias preguntas/respuestas de un mismo usuario. Tenéis más información [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/qu%C3%A9-es-el-voto-serial-y-c%C3%B3mo-me-afecta).

También comentas que:

> Otro detalle que quería comentarles es que, sospechosamente luego de haber realizado esos reclamos, he recibido otra votación negativa, pero en otra pregunta.

He revisado la pregunta que comentas y no hay ningún comportamiento sospechoso detectado. Lo más probable es que *otro* usuario haya realizado ese voto.

---

Por lo que voy a lo que pides al final por puntos:

> Que se anulen las votaciones negativas incorrectas.

No se van a anular esas votaciones ya que están justificadas dentro de su subjetividad. Aunque estuviera de acuerdo con tu postura la comunidad es libre de votar como le parezca mejor, aunque no siempre sea lo correcto según una opinión personal que es subjetiva.

> Que haya quita de puntos para los usuarios que votaron incorrectamente.

No se ha detectado ningún voto fraudulento o mala intención por ninguno de los participantes en la pregunta (que pueden o no pueden ser los que han votado negativamente, recuerdo que los votos son confidenciales).

> Que se implemente un sistema de control para que los moderadores sean controlados por sus pares o por integrantes de más autoridad.

Eso ya existe. Los moderadores podemos ver de manera fácil las distintas actuaciones realizadas por otros moderadores y te aseguro que por mi parte siempre miro lo que realiza, en este caso, Luiggi. Y voy a añadir que des de que soy moderador coincido siempre con sus acciones. Luiggi tiene mucha más experiencia que yo y tengo que destacar que hace muchísimo trabajo de moderador y de calidad.

Repito, eso ya existe. Y además se utiliza. Os aseguro que trabajamos en equipo y cualquier decisión que se tome por parte de un moderador casi siempre está consensuada entre nosotros. Nos comunicamos de manera periódica e intentamos tomar las mejores decisiones de moderador para la comunidad.

> Impedir que alguien pueda borrar una respuesta, cuando ésta tiene un comentario donde se solicita la mejora de la misma, ajustándose a lo que pide la pregunta, so pena de recibir calificaciones negativas.

Para esto te recomiendo que publiques una nueva pregunta independiente en meta con el tag [característica-nueva](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%C3%ADstica-nueva). Así la comunidad podrá opinar al respecto. Aunque sea moderador estas decisiones recaen sobre la comunidad, y eso me parece genial.