# ¿Por qué votan negativo sin dar ninguna explicación al respecto?

Tags: discusión

Llevo observando varios días que me votan negativo a respuestas que yo considero correctas (se parecen mucho a la respuesta más votada -no copiadas, ya que conteste antes incluso- o incluso el OP me ha dicho que le ha servido mi respuesta en alguna de ellas) pero sin explicación ninguna del motivo por el cual se me está votando negativo.

Estas son las preguntas en las cuales he recibido voto negativo en mi respuesta:

- [¿Cómo detectar click en un ListView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28741/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-click-en-un-listview/28750#28750)
- [Volver a la actividad padre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29542/volver-a-la-actividad-padre/29543#29543)
- [Error con Fragments: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29342/error-con-fragments-java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragmentmanager-is-alread/29345#29345)

Sinceramente veo muy bien que se me vote negativo si es para darme una crítica constructiva de porque la respuesta está mal, incluso lo agradezco, porque de los errores es cuando mejor se aprende pero creo que los votos negativos sin una crítica no tienen valor ninguno.

También he llegado a pensar que es alguien que me ha cogido manía y por eso me vota negativo. ¿Eso se puede llegar a controlar de alguna manera?

No me importa que me voten negativo, como he dicho antes, pero siempre que dejen una crítica constructiva.

¿Por qué la gente vota negativo sin dejar una crítica sobre la respuesta/pregunta a la que han votado?

Comment: No todos tienen tu buena actitud en cuanto a recibir crítica constructiva, de modo que muchos prefieren votar negativamente de forma anónima para evitar discusiones o votos vengativos. Me ha sucedido en el pasado. Pero, en lo personal, justamente debido a que hay personas como tu, usualmente me obligo a dejar un comentario junto con el voto.

Comment: Error404, entiendo el por que lo preguntas, he recibido muchos downvotes en los 11 meses que lleva el sitio y a mi parecer, prácticamente todos son injustificados. Datos interesantes, búscate en el ranking XD... http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/edit/563810

Comment: @rnd No sabía que se podían hacer tales queries aquí en stackoverflow aunque parecen bastante interesantes. ¿Cómo has llegado hasta ella?

Comment: @Error404 la hize yo mismo (la goolie de otro sitio y la arme para SOes) en una base de datos, llamada SEDE, que contiene toda la info de Stack Exchange.. ese link es dentro de SEDE. salu2

Comment: @Error404 desgraciadamente es opinión personal de cada usuario, algo subjetivo que puede dar cabida a errores. Recuerdo hace poco una pregunta en la cual habían 4 respuestas, 3 de ellas podrían considerarse correctas pero la única que tenía votos a favor era una respuesta que sugería agregar algo que ya se tenia en la pregunta, no vote en contra pero me llamo mucho la atención, de hecho en ocasiones pregunto "de donde eres", personalmente he notado algunos grupos de personas que se apoyan entre sí. Creo que si no conocemos un poco de lo que habla la pregunta tratemos de no votar.

Comment: @Elenasys Sí, yo también he observado ese comportamiento. No en SOes pero si en stackoverflow en inglés así que supongo que se dará en la mayoría de stackexchange

Comment: @Error404 concuerdo 100% contigo, esto ensucia la comunidad, por gente odiosa. Creo que si la comunidad es de preguntas/respuestas la clave es enseñar para aprender y claramente hay muchos usuarios que no lo ven asi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ¿Por qué la gente vota negativo sin dejar una crítica sobre la respuesta/pregunta a la que han votado?

Eso es una opinión personal de cada usuario. Hay usuarios que cuándo votan negativamente casi siempre dejan un comentario y otros que no, realmente [no hay ninguna obligación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/927/7242) y aunque es de agradecer no se puede hacer nada al respeto.

> Estas son las preguntas en las cuales he recibido voto negativo en mi respuesta

Sobre tus respuestas, en mi opinión personal las veo correctas y no merecedoras de un downvote por lo que en ese sentido no te puedo ayudar, son buenas respuestas. A lo sumo se podrían mejorar con enlaces a documentación de algunas cosas que comentas pero poco más.

> También he llegado a pensar que es alguien que me ha cogido manía y por eso me vota negativo. ¿Eso se puede llegar a controlar de alguna manera?

Esto se puede controlar y se controla. Existen 2 sistemas, uno automático y otro manual.

- El proceso automático se ejecuta diariamente para controlar el [voto serial](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/663/7242). Este proceso capta os votos en cortos intervalos de tiempo de un mismo usuario sobre otro usuario. Se desconocen exactamente las normas que rigen este proceso para evitar que se pueda saltar este sistema.
- El proceso manual está disponible para los moderadores dónde se analizan patrones de votos sospechosos independientemente del tiempo entre voto y voto. He analizado tu usuario y no es el caso (detectado por este método).

*Puede* ser posible que alguien te esté votando negativamente pero no da esa sensación. Lo más probable es que usuarios de manera completamente aliena hayan realizado esos downvotes dándose la casuística de que en ninguno de los casos han dejado comentario alguno, pero no hay motivo para preocuparse.

Más allá de eso, aunque uno reciba votos negativos sin justificación (a todos nos pasa), lo mejor es continuar adelante ya que con buen contenido los votos positivos vendrán por sí solos y estoy convencido que en tu caso va a ser así.

P.D.: Además ahora estás bajo el [efecto meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) =P

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me has dejado claros todos los puntos en los que tenía dudas. No me preocupan realmente los puntos negativos si no que al final me hacían dudar de la redacción y calidad de mis respuestas (que no digo que sean perfectas pero intento ayudar lo mejor que se) y no sabía que hacía mal.

Comment: Creo que [este voto negativo de esta respuesta tuya](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29542/volver-a-la-actividad-padre/29543#29543) es porque se equivocaron y creyeron que repetiste la misma respuesta, pero no vieron que tu respondiste mucho antes xD, al menos eso creo yo (No pienses que fui yo, solo lo vi :p)

Comment: @x4mp73r Si, yo pensé lo mismo. O que pensaron que al ver la respuesta con imágenes la mía no valía tanto aunque (y es opinión personal) "lo bueno, si breve, dos veces bueno".

Comment: Muy buena reflexión... tanto el StackOverflow original como éste tienen un serio problema con estas cosas. En StaxkOverflow English ya di la batalla por perdida: "mod bot zombis" que parece que sólo saben hacer copy-paste de dircursos con HowTos sin haber leído ni la pregunta. En plan "me echas la charla del Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible"  **lee la pregunta ahí está tu ejemplo mínimo reproducible** ... y encima los moderadores de Meta defendiendo a ese desgraciado "está curando el sitio" mis huevos!! Lo está envenenando. (si sentís curiosidad os posteo el hilo por aquí)

Answer (score 9):

Cito una respuesta de [Miquel Coll♦ en otro hilo de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/927/2742) (el resaltado es mío):

> (...) los downvotes:
>
> - **No se requiere explicación alguna**.
> - **Todo el mundo es libre de votar como quiera** sin tener que dar explicaciones.
> - Sólo existe 1 caso en que los downvotes son "eliminados": Serial downvoting, cuándo un mismo usuario vota negativamente en un corto plazo de tiempo a varias preguntas/respuestas de un mismo usuario. Tenéis más información [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/qu%C3%A9-es-el-voto-serial-y-c%C3%B3mo-me-afecta).

Eso en cuanto la dinámica general de los votos negativos. Estos votos son libres, anónimos (incluso para los moderadores) y controlados.

En cuanto mi opinión personal, opino que los votos negativos deben ir acompañados de una explicación, a mi también me molesta que estos votos no incluyan el motivo aunque también entiendo la motivación detrás de la libertad de no añadir explicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Sé que los votos son libres de cada uno   pero al final te hacen dudar de la calidad de tus respuestas y de si estás realizando algo erróneamente.

Comment: Coincido con esta respuesta ya que es decisión de cada uno al igual que el "seleccionado" de respuesta.

Comment: +1 por la dinámica general de los votos. Aún cuando las respuestas que son correctas _o que son mas completas o cualquier otro criterio_ reciben votos negativos, la misma comunidad _una vez vaya creciendo_ llegarán a estas respuestas y votarán a favor. Desconozco si hay personas que "trolean" con el tema de los votos negativos, pero no hay que tomarlo tan a pecho, se debe seguir y mejorar cada día.

Comment: @Mauricio Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tu comentario. Realmente los votos negativos sirven para aprender y no cometer los mismos errores una y otra vez. Sin embargo, parece que haya veces que la gente se dedique a dar votos negativos sin pararse del todo a mirar las respuestas.