# Durante un año "me he hecho pasar" por mujer en StackOverflow.es

Tags: discusión

Este tema es la introducción al de [Aceptación, apoyo y positividad de las publicaciones hechas por mujeres en StackOverflow.es](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3808/2742).

En diciembre de 2017 decidí hacer una *inocentada* en el sitio cambiando mi identidad; transformé mi perfil en el de una mujer. Por supuesto, los miembros de SO.es vieron inmediatamente a través del engaño pues que un día desaparezca un conocido usuario con 11k de reputación para ser reemplazado por una usuaria desconocida con 11k de reputación es bastante sospechoso:

> - [@Paula_plus_plus ¿Tu nick anterior era paper bird master?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=42608387#42608387)
> - [Paula_plus_plus es Paper???](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=42060623#42060623)

Decidí mantener "*el engaño*" durante un año para llevar a cabo un experimento.

## Motivación.

Quería vivir de primera mano la experiencia de ser una mujer en internet, en un entorno mayoritariamente masculino y en un contexto tecnológico ya que he leído y escuchado terribles historias de lo hostil, peligroso, poco colaborador, sexista y excluyente que es ese tipo de entornos para las mujeres, por poner unos ejemplos<sup>1</sup>:

- [What Is It Like To Be A Woman In A STEM Field?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/07/07/what-is-it-like-to-be-a-woman-in-a-stem-field).

  - Los líderes veteranos en academias pueden ser a veces "alfa": agresivos y dominantes. La gente que usa tonos más afables y **las mujeres (de tono afable o no) pueden verse silenciadas o no escuchadas en estos contextos**.
- [Women and Men in STEM Often at Odds Over Workplace Equity](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2018/01/09/women-and-men-in-stem-often-at-odds-over-workplace-equity/).

  - **La percepción de inequidad es especialmente común entre mujeres** en trabajos de ciencia, tecnología, ingeniería y matemáticas **que trabajan mayoritariamente con hombres**.
  - **Para las mujeres** en trabajos de ciencia, tecnología, ingeniería y matemáticas, el lugar de trabajo es diferente, **a veces el entorno es más hostil que el que experimentan sus compañeros hombres**.
- [Evento dedicado a la industria del videojuego y exclusivo de mujeres](https://gamingladiesbcn.wordpress.com/faq/).

  - Por último, pero no menos importante, **queremos ofrecer un “entorno seguro”**. Cuando hablamos de entornos o espacios seguros femeninos no hacemos alusión al temor por la integridad física en presencia masculina, sino al ambiente que se crea cuando se comparten experiencias sensibles dentro de un grupo homogéneo que puede sentirse identificado con el problema tratado. **Intercambiar experiencias y opiniones cuando la audiencia es parte afectada es siempre más eficiente y seguro, ya que es posible expresarse sin temor a sentirse juzgada, humillada o cuestionada**.

Las historias de acoso, menosprecio, sexismo y hostilidad no coinciden con las experiencias que he tenido en casi tres lustros trabajando como programador ni con más de veinte años teniendo la tecnología como *hobby* (en especial videojuegos y su desarrollo); en todo ese tiempo y en los entornos laborales y de ocio con mayoría masculina las veces que una mujer formaba parte del grupo era tratada con respeto, en ocasiones admiración, e incluso con una amabilidad y atención que no se ofrecía a los hombres.

Vivir de primera mano la existencia de esa negatividad dirigida a las mujeres en los entornos tecnológicos con mayoría masculina es lo que me ha motivado a hacerme pasar por mujer durante un año.

## Hipótesis.

Las mujeres, en ambientes en que hay mayoría de hombres y en especial en ambientes técnicos, son menospreciadas (sus aportaciones no se tienen en cuenta), tratadas con hostilidad y sexismo e incluso reciben ataques sexistas.

## Preparación.

Para comprobar la hipótesis, era necesario interactuar con la mayor cantidad de usuarios posible. Cuantas más interacciones, más probabilidad de experimentar una situación de acoso, sexista u hostil; mi perfil durante 2018 ha sido ideal para ello ya que:

- Tiene un [impacto superior a los 350k](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742).
- Forma parte del <1% general del sitio.
- Forma parte del [top 10 del sitio](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/alltime/es-stackoverflow).
- Forma parte del [top 20 de 2018](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/year/es-stackoverflow).
- Forma parte del [top 5 de la etiqueta C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers).

Para que el perfil tuviese apariencia femenina seguí los siguientes pasos:

1. Me hice una foto y [la retoqué con FaceApp para cambiar de sexo](https://faceapp.com/filters/change-gender/article), evitando así robar a alguien su identidad.
2. Cambié el nombre del perfil a uno claramente femenino.
3. Borré el "Acerca de" en mi perfil.
4. Cambié mi localización de Barcelona (ES) a Barcelona (VE) para tener una excusa (la distancia) para no quedar si alguien quería conocerme en persona.
5. Usé una redacción de género neutro o en género femenino para redactar mis preguntas y respuestas.

[image]

Usaré abreviaciones para referirme a los siguientes conceptos:

- **F**: Perfil aparentemente Femenino. Un perfil del sitio SO.es que a primera vista podría considerarse que pertenece a una mujer. En los gráficos he usado el color verde para representarlo.
- **NoF**: Perfil aparentemente No Femenino. Un perfil del sitio SO.es que a primera vista NO podría considerarse que pertenece a una mujer. En los gráficos he usado el color rojo para representarlo.

He utilizado el año 2017 (Noviembre 16 a Noviembre 17) como muestra de perfil NoF; no he utilizado el 2016 porque fue mi año inicial y no tuve la misma participación que en años posteriores. El año 2018 (Noviembre 17 a Noviembre 18) es la muestra de F.

Utilizo el término "*Aparentemente Femenino/No Femenino*" porque, aparte de las apariencias, no hay maneras de asegurar que un perfil de SO.es pertenece a una mujer o a un hombre; además, alguien puede estar usando un perfil que no refleje su realidad (como en mi caso) y esto puede suceder en F y NoF, por ello asumo que existe un margen de error desconocido en ambos sentidos (F considerado NoF y viceversa).

#### A tener en cuenta.

Todo el experimento es más improvisado que premeditado, por ello no puedo garantizar que la metodología sea la más adecuada ni la preparación ha sido todo lo exhaustiva que debería haber sido (cualquier persona con suficiente interés y conocimiento podría analizar mi perfil y ver el engaño).

Por ello no quiero que se tome mi experiencia como una muestra de lo que viven en general las mujeres en Internet, en un entorno mayoritariamente masculino ni en un entorno tecnológico. Pero sí que quiero que se tome como una muestra de lo que es tener F relevante y visible en una famosa página de tecnología con una presencia femenina anecdótica.

## Apoyo y aceptación.

Voy a analizar el apoyo y aceptación que recibió mi F respecto a mi NoF, para ello compararé los votos recibidos, la posición en el top 100 de la página y cuántas de las respuestas publicadas fueron aceptadas.

### Reputación y posición en la liga<sup>A</sup>.

En líneas se muestra mi posición en el top 100 del sitio y en columnas el acumulado de reputación<sup>2</sup> en el mismo periodo:
[image]

Podemos observar que F ha sido más relevante que NoF:

- El F ha estado más presente en la mitad superior del top 25.
- El NoF estuvo más presente en la mitad inferior del top 25.

Respecto a aceptación y apoyo, mi crecimiento en el sitio ha sido notablemente mayor con F:

- La ganancia de reputación con F ha sido de 9551 puntos.
- La ganancia de reputación con NoF fue de 7328 puntos.

Si analizamos los meses por separado, vemos que salvo mayo, junio, julio y noviembre, la aceptación del F ha sido mayor que la del NoF:
[image]
Cabe destacar que los meses en que el NoF ganó más reputación ganó poca más que el F, mientras que los meses en que el F ganó más reputación, ganó considerablemente más que el NoF.

### Votos en publicaciones.

La distribución de los votos del F y del NoF, en horizontal la cantidad de votos de una publicación y en vertical la cantidad de publicaciones con esa cantidad de votos:
[image]
De nuevo F es más relevante:

- Tiene menos publicaciones con 0 votos.
- En la mayoría de tramos, tiene más publicaciones.

Con excepciones:

- NoF tiene más publicaciones con cantidades elevadas (más de 10) votos.

Esta distribución de votos hace que F haya tenido más positividad que NoF<sup>3</sup>:
[image]

### Aceptación.

De las respuestas publicadas con F y NoF, usando F conseguí un índice mayor de aceptación:
[image]

#### A tener en cuenta.

Las comparaciones NoF contra F tienen los siguientes problemas:

- Los datos de 2017 y 2018 corresponden a un usuario reputado y consolidado, mi perfil ya tenía relevancia antes del experimento y una tendencia ascendente en reputación y relevancia (llega un momento que un usuario de esas características puede crecer por su propia fama).
- También debo señalar que los años estudiados han sido diferentes: ni he tenido la misma dedicación al sitio en 2017 y en 2018, ni he tenido las vacaciones en los mismos periodos, ni el sitio tenía la misma fama e importancia en 2017 que en 2018, ni la misma cantidad de usuarios registrados.
- He tenido una dedicación y compromiso con SO.es muy alta en ambos años, pero cargas de trabajo diferentes que me apartaban de dedicar a este proyecto el mismo tiempo, por ello, se puede ver en los dos últimos gráficos que 2018 (periodo de F) he respondido más que en 2017 (periodo de NoF) en concreto 167 frente a 125.

### Hostilidad y toxicidad.

Tengo una manera de redactar y participar en SO.es que algunas personas tildan de seca, prepotente o repelente. En general se podría considerar mi manera de participar en el sitio como propensa a generar respuestas hostiles, por ejemplo:

- [Error en programa de estadística c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132421/error-en-programa-de-estad%C3%ADstica-): Es una pregunta eliminada, adjunto una captura de los comentarios.

[image]

Sin embargo, rara vez he tenido problemas en la comunidad de SO.es, pero mentiría si dijera que me he librado de recibir reacciones hostiles a mi participación en el sitio, por ejemplo:

- NoF: [Votaciones que atentan contra la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/926/2742) .
- F: [Pero vamos a ver. La pregunta es sencilla y clara. Que tú no la entiendas es otra cosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219804/c%C3%B3mo-implemento-la-declaraci%C3%B3n-de-una-matriz-la-siguiente-matriz-inicializada/219808#comment408870_219808).

Tildar esas reacciones de hostilidad sea tal vez estirar mucho el término, pero es difícil encontrar reacciones extremas de hostilidad en un ambiente poco propenso a ello, os invito a buscar otras reacciones complementarias.

En general no puedo decir que haya notado un aumento de la hostilidad usando F respecto a NoF, pero sí que tengo la sensación de haber recibido más mensajes positivos y palabras de agradecimiento con F que con NoF, pero solo es una sensación, podéis repasar mi historial de comentarios recibidos<sup>C</sup> para ver si llegáis a la misma conclusión.

### Acoso.

Una de las cosas que esperaba experimentar usando F era recibir mensajes privados cuya naturaleza no fuese relacionada con el sitio (programación). Si bien he recibido mensajes privados durante 2018, ninguno de ellos ha sido para temas no relacionados con la programación. Pero sí que he recibido mensajes que no sé de qué manera clasificar (por ejemplo, cuando me abren una sala de chat para [decirme "?"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72215/room-for-osmelg-and-paula-plus-plus). Aún contando los (pocos) mensajes inexplicables, no puedo decir que haya experimentado acoso.

Creo que vale la pena señalar que tanto con F como con NoF he recibido invitaciones a salas de chat para hablar de programación.

## Conclusión.

No he podido apreciar ninguna disminución de relevancia o apoyo en los años comparados (F durante 2018, NoF durante 2017), al contrario: he notado un aumento del apoyo recibido y en general una mayor aceptación, esto puede deberse a:

#### F ha tenido un efecto negativo, pero mitigado por otros efectos positivos.

Mi F ha tenido un impacto negativo respecto a NoF, pero la negatividad se ha mitigado por otros efectos positivos (como el efecto "*vivir de la fama previa*", el apoyo de usuarios que conocían la verdadera identidad del perfil o la mayor dedicación al sitio en 2018 respecto 2017) de manera que aunque haya crecido la importancia, apoyo y relevancia de mi perfil, podría haber crecido más durante 2018 de no haber sido lastrado por un F.

No considero esta explicación factible por los siguientes motivos:

- El efecto "*vivir de la fama previa*": Es posible que parte de los puntos recibidos en 2018 provengan de publicaciones de 2016 y 2017, pero dado que los cambios en el perfil son retroactivos, si alguien votó durante 2018 en publicaciones de 2016 o 2017 lo haría sobre un F, si hubiera voluntad de menospreciar un F, no recibiría esos votos. Pese a ello, se debería estudiar un factor de corrección de la reputación en base a que cuanto más participativo es un usuario, más reputación puede ganar de preguntas antiguas.
- El apoyo de usuarios que conocían mi identidad: Los usuarios conocedores de mi identidad son pocos, aún contando que fuesen varias veces más, seguirían sin ser mayoría y aún siendo mayoría no todos ellos votan en mis publicaciones. Además, los nuevos usuarios de SO.es no deberían conocer ni mi identidad ni la de otros usuarios.
- Mayor dedicación en periodo de F frente al de NoF: Podríamos pensar que una mayor dedicación a SO.es en el periodo de F podría haberme hecho ganar más apoyo y relevancia, pero eso entonces sería una contradicción frente a la idea de que los F son menospreciados ya que a mayor número de interacciones, más se habría notado el menosprecio.
- Si existiera una voluntad de menospreciar los perfiles femeninos debería haberse reflejado en un crecimiento menor o negativo al comparar 2018 respecto a 2017.
- Si se asume que el menosprecio a F existió por parte de usuarios nuevos, pero fue mitigado por el apoyo de usuarios veteranos que conocían mi perfil verdadero el crecimiento debería haber sido igualmente menor o negativo, raramente muy superior como ha sido el caso.

#### El apoyo y aceptación del F es fruto del [sexismo benevolente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambivalent_sexism).

Una de las manifestaciones del sexismo benevolente es la idealización de las mujeres, poniéndolas en un pedestal («*men's dependence on women is what fuels benevolently sexist attitudes, leading to idolization and the placing of women on a pedestal*» —[Glick and Fiske](http://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0022-3514.70.3.491)—); este efecto se podría manifestar de forma que las publicaciones con F fuesen juzgadas con menos dureza o que frente a publicaciones similares se escogiese apoyar más la del F frente a la del NoF.

Esta explicación se ajusta más a mis observaciones, y el efecto del sexismo benevolente también ha sido observado en otros contextos:

- [Un estudio Australiano usando *currículos ciegos*](https://pmc.gov.au/sites/default/files/publications/BETA-report-going-blind-to-see-more%20clearly.pdf) descubrió que cuando se eliminan los datos personales de los CV (género, etnicidad, edad, etc...) las posibilidades de contratar a una mujer bajaban ligeramente respecto a cuando los mismos datos estaban presentes.
- He observado que en algunas de las preguntas en las que participé con F, mi respuesta fue aceptada o recibió mayor apoyo que otras respuestas más tempranas y/o mejores:

  - [Puntero this en función con objeto por referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131367/2742) : Respondí casi dos horas más tarde, aportando muy poco respecto a lo ya respondido, pese a ello recibí el visto bueno.
  - [Uso de memoria en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/138408/2742) : Respondí más pronto, pero mi respuesta era menos detallada y menos trabajada, pese a ello recibí el visto bueno.
  - [Entender la clase árbol binario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/146150/2742) : Respondí dos horas más tarde, aportando casi lo mismo a lo ya respondido, pese a ello recibí el visto bueno.
  - Podéis buscar más ejemplos en mi historial de respuestas aceptadas de 2018<sup>B</sup>.

Pero aún cuando el sexismo benevolente parece una explicación factible, me resisto a aceptar esta conclusión ya que es discutible que mis respuestas fuesen peores o que mereciesen menos atención (podemos debatirlo).

#### No ha habido ninguna voluntad de menospreciar mi perfil por el hecho de ser F.

El crecimiento en apoyo y aceptación de mi perfil en general se podría explicar como el efecto de ser un perfil relevante en SO.es que, aparte de crecer por efectos acumulativos previos (crecer en base a la fama adquirida previamente), podría crecer porque mis participaciones gustan *per se*, sin que el hecho de que sea un F o un NoF afecte en nada.

---

En mi opinión, parece que tener un F o un NoF no afecta al valor que se le da a las intervenciones de dicho perfil o en caso de afectar, lo hace de manera ligeramente positiva hacia un F.

Respecto a situaciones de hostilidad y acoso, las situaciones que podrían describirse como tal han sido tan escasas y de tan poca importancia que me inclino a decir que no ha habido un aumento de esos problemas con F respecto a NoF.

---

1. Es una corta selección de artículos usando Google con búsquedas como "stem is hostile to women" o "mujeres en tecnología", podéis ver más artículos del tema haciendo búsquedas parecidas.
2. La diferencia entre el mes y el primer mes de la muestra, por eso Diciembre es 0.
3. La positividad se calcula sumando toda la puntuación positiva de las publicaciones. La indiferencia se calcula contando todas las publicaciones que tuvieron 0 votos. La negatividad se calcula sumando toda la puntuación negativa de las publicaciones.

---

Los datos se han recopilado de la [liga del sitio](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637) o de la [base de datos de SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/es).

- A: Los datos están sacados de:

  - La [liga del
    sitio](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/alltime/es-stackoverflow).
  - Mis publicaciones clasificadas por cantidad de votos recibidos.

    ```
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) Y,
        Score,
        COUNT(Score) Posts
      FROM
        Posts
      WHERE
        OwnerUserId = 2742
      GROUP BY
        DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate),
        Score
    ) SOURCE PIVOT (SUM(Posts) FOR Y IN ([2017], [2018])) PTABLE
    ```
  - Positividad, Indiferencia y Negatividad de mis publicaciones:

    ```
      SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) Y,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN Score END) Positividad,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Score = 0 THEN 1 END) Indiferencia,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Score < 0 THEN -Score END) Negatividad
      FROM
        Posts
      WHERE
        OwnerUserId = 2742
      GROUP BY
        DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate)
    ```
  - Mis respuestas no aceptadas y mis respuestas aceptadas.

    ```
      SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
          'Aceptadas' Grupo,
          DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) Y,
          COUNT(Id) Total
        FROM
          Posts P
        WHERE
          (SELECT OwnerUserId FROM Posts WHERE Id = P.AcceptedAnswerId) = 2742
        GROUP BY
          DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate)
        UNION
        SELECT
          'No-Aceptadas' Grupo,
          DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) Y,
          COUNT(Id) Total
        FROM
          Posts P
        WHERE
          PostTypeId = 2 AND
          OwnerUserId = 2742 AND
          (SELECT AcceptedAnswerId FROM Posts WHERE Id = P.ParentId) != P.Id
        GROUP BY
          DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate)
      ) SOURCE PIVOT (SUM(Total) FOR Y IN([2017], [2018])) PTABLE
    ```
- B: Respuestas que he hecho durante 2018 que han sido aceptadas en preguntas en que hay más de una respuesta.

  ```
  SELECT
    'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/' + CAST(Id as VARCHAR) url
  FROM
    Posts S
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 2 AND
    OwnerUserId = 2742 AND
    DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) = 2018 AND
    (SELECT AcceptedAnswerId FROM Posts WHERE Id = S.ParentId) = S.Id AND
    (SELECT AnswerCount FROM Posts WHERE Id = S.ParentId) > 1
  ```
- C: Comentarios en respuestas mías en 2017 y 2018.

  ```
  SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) Y,
    'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/' + CAST(PostId as VARCHAR) url,
    Text
  FROM
    Comments C
  WHERE
    (SELECT OwnerUserId FROM Posts P WHERE P.Id = C.PostId) = 2742 AND
    UserId != 2742 AND
    DATEPART(YEAR, CreationDate) IN (2017, 2018)
  ```
- D: Todos los "Acerca de" del sitio:

  ```
  SELECT
    AboutMe
  FROM
    Users
  WHERE
    LEN(AboutMe) > 0
  ```

---

Pueden verse datos adicionales en [esta hoja de cálculo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_YwG-Hsjd8BgZIqCPml7lxH2zBzE4qf6hw5Wrsr8tc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Detalle repelente: ¿Escribir Veneçuela (catalán) en lugar de Venezuela en tu perfil fue algo hecho a propósito?

Comment: Muy interesante el análisis.
Dado que soy nuevo por aquí, era imposible que imaginase la "suplantación".
Siempre que he votado alguna respuesta tuya, en ningún caso me ha condicionado el "sexismo benevolente", siempre me han parecido respuestas muy bien elaboradas y explicadas.

Comment: Yo personalmente esperaba una conclusión en la misma linea. Enhorabuena por el experimento y por la presentación de resultados. Supongo que imaginas que esto no convencerá a nadie de todas maneras...

Comment: @PabloLozano en mi perfil sale Veneçuela porque tengo el ordenador y navegador en Catalán, supongo que si alguien con el navegador en otro idioma visita mi perfil lo verá diferente. A tu pregunta: no está hecho a posta.

Comment: @meegle84 dices no haber sido afectado por el "sexismo benevolente" y me inclino a pensar que es cierto pero… ¿podemos decir lo mismo de otras personas?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus solo puedo hablar desde mi punto de vista, aunque según comentas `mi respuesta fue aceptada o recibió mayor apoyo que otras respuestas más tempranas y/o mejores`, quizá si que ha existido por otras personas

Comment: cuando vi la foto ya le di el +1 a la publicacion

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado, [Gender differences in participation and reward on Stack Overflow](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10664-019-09685-x)

Comment: @Pikoh muy interesante. Me ha gustado la parte en que separan los perfiles F de los NoF de una manera similar a la mía (similar, pero yo trabajé con menos medios, menos datos de entrada y de manera menos sistemática); me hace pensar que no iba errado en mi criba. Sin embargo el tema central del documento es estudiar la presencia de mujeres en IT no si las mujeres sufren ataques en las comunidades IT. También me parece que parten de la conclusión (las mujeres están discriminadas) e hilan el discurso desde ahí en lugar de partir de la hipótesis e intentar confirmarla/desmentirla.

Comment: Por eso he puesto _posiblemente_ relacionado. En el estudio en concreto, no se habla de discriminación individual (no habla de ataques), pero si sistematica (dado que como preguntan mas y las preguntas se puntuan menos, hay una discriminación.) Curiosamente, hace un par de dias se recalculó la reputación de las preguntas doblandola :)

Comment: "*Las preguntas puntúan menos, ergo discriminación*" es una conclusión sin sentido. Si tan atractivas son las respuestas (a nivel de reputación) lo único que hay que hacer para cultivar reputación es responder… al fin y al cabo responder no se prohíbe según criterios arbitrarios: está al alcance de todos.

Comment: _Hostilidad y toxicidad_ : Sin importar el género siempre habrá un paso de distancia hacia el precipicio a la hostilidad y toxicidad aventurarse hacer "juicios de valores" como parte de las respuestas y/o comentarios, y no solo en SO, pasa en todas las interacciones humanos, así que yo lo descartaría como métrica a considerar.

Comment: @Ale la hostilidad y toxicidad se han tenido en cuenta porque la narrativa es que los perfiles F reciben ese tipo de interacciones en mayor medida.

Comment: Como llegué a esta publicacion? xD  (edit: ya vi, la mandaron en el chat) Interesante experimento PaperBirdMaster!