# Aceptación, apoyo y positividad de las publicaciones hechas por mujeres en StackOverflow.es

Tags: discusión

Como anexo al hilo en que [*Durante un año "me he hecho pasar" por mujer en StackOverflow.es*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3807/2742), he repetido el mismo análisis con los perfiles Femeninos de SO.es.

## Motivación.

He leído y escuchado terribles historias de lo hostil, peligroso, poco colaborador, sexista y excluyente que son para las mujeres los entornos dominados por hombres, en especial aquellos relacionados con la tecnología, por poner unos ejemplos<sup>1</sup>:

- [What Is It Like To Be A Woman In A STEM Field?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/07/07/what-is-it-like-to-be-a-woman-in-a-stem-field).

  - Los líderes veteranos en academias pueden ser a veces "alfa": agresivos y dominantes. La gente que usa tonos más afables y **las mujeres (de tono afable o no) pueden verse silenciadas o no escuchadas en estos contextos**.
- [Women and Men in STEM Often at Odds Over Workplace Equity](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2018/01/09/women-and-men-in-stem-often-at-odds-over-workplace-equity/).

  - **La percepción de inequidad es especialmente común entre mujeres** en trabajos de ciencia, tecnología, ingeniería y matemáticas **que trabajan mayoritariamente con hombres**.
  - **Para las mujeres** en trabajos de ciencia, tecnología, ingeniería y matemáticas, el lugar de trabajo es diferente, **a veces el entorno es más hostil que el que experimentan sus compañeros hombres**.
- [Evento dedicado a la industria del videojuego y exclusivo de mujeres](https://gamingladiesbcn.wordpress.com/faq/).

  - Por último, pero no menos importante, **queremos ofrecer un “entorno seguro”**. Cuando hablamos de entornos o espacios seguros femeninos no hacemos alusión al temor por la integridad física en presencia masculina, sino al ambiente que se crea cuando se comparten experiencias sensibles dentro de un grupo homogéneo que puede sentirse identificado con el problema tratado. **Intercambiar experiencias y opiniones cuando la audiencia es parte afectada es siempre más eficiente y seguro, ya que es posible expresarse sin temor a sentirse juzgada, humillada o cuestionada**.

Las historias de acoso, menosprecio, sexismo y hostilidad no coinciden con las experiencias que he tenido en casi tres lustros trabajando como programador ni con más de veinte años teniendo la tecnología como hobby (en especial videojuegos y su desarrollo); en todo ese tiempo y en los entornos laborales y de ocio con mayoría masculina las veces que una mujer formaba parte del grupo era tratada con respeto, en ocasiones admiración, e incluso con una amabilidad y atención que no se ofrecía a los hombres.

Vivir de primera mano la existencia de esa negatividad dirigida a las mujeres en los entornos tecnológicos con mayoría masculina es lo que me ha motivado a hacerme pasar por mujer durante un año.

### Preparación.

Dado que la red SO no almacena datos de género en su Base de Datos, intenté deducir el género de los usuarios tras el perfil en base a analizar las características de los mismos, consideré que un perfil sería F si:

1. **En el "Acerca de" del perfil la persona se refería a si misma en femenino**: extraje todos los "Acerca de" del sitio<sup>D</sup> y los separé por palabras y cada palabra la clasifiqué según si la usaría o no exclusivamente una mujer (por ejemplo la palabra "egresada" es muy improbable que la use un hombre para referirse a si mismo pero la palabra "universitaria" podría usarla una mujer o un hombre indistintamente), también hice búsqueda con frases como "soy una" que no fuese seguido de "persona".
2. **El nombre del perfil parece femenino**: Con el proceso anterior, conseguí varios nombres de usuario que podrían considerarse nombres femeninos y los usé para buscar usuarios con nombres parecidos a éstos nombres base.
3. **La foto de perfil parece femenina**: Con todos los perfiles recopilados en los puntos anteriores, pasé perfil a perfil eliminando falsos positivos y eliminando los que tuviera dudas de que pudieran ser perfiles femeninos con la premisa de "Si dudas que es un F es un NoF".

Siguiendo esas guías, conseguí un listado de 468 perfiles que una gran parte de personas podrían considerar F:

```
96,371,1003,1119,1698,1965,2867,3004,3393,3818,5403,7015,7067,7164,7202,7380,7492,7582,8957,9452,9962,9992,10060,10137,10451,10511,10583,11351,11380,13177,13316,13522,13617,14383,14547,14622,15005,15095,15811,16483,16649,16909,17996,18379,18532,19481,19749,19997,20010,20054,20122,20223,20659,21308,22091,22379,22463,22573,22603,23289,23746,23944,24072,24123,24232,24238,24616,24694,24867,25493,25717,25836,26201,26489,26759,26969,27495,27503,27563,27632,27856,28058,28065,28583,28752,29059,29132,29166,29240,30212,30401,30453,31212,31233,31404,31588,31769,31956,32096,32301,32532,32563,32586,32892,33306,33377,33629,33661,33955,34071,34094,34782,35254,35284,35316,35342,35391,35401,35965,36073,37308,37438,37820,37911,37920,38018,38191,38258,38267,38734,38808,39204,39314,39671,40226,40468,40894,41087,41328,41339,41581,41830,42133,42257,42380,42731,43028,43155,43226,43553,43623,43863,44208,44800,45258,45771,45972,46554,46576,46590,47046,47523,47752,47845,47959,48986,49340,49377,49481,49546,49892,49893,50003,50094,50125,50143,50291,50410,50453,50486,50507,50661,50765,50970,50991,51034,51338,51464,51724,51737,51952,52151,52300,52391,53885,53941,53986,54296,54314,54523,54962,55190,55355,55538,55612,56280,56739,56957,57266,57312,57322,57536,57545,57626,58017,58246,58399,58432,58598,58707,58812,59102,59126,59392,59549,59584,59812,59825,59886,60313,60371,60579,61194,61639,61640,61957,62083,62084,62223,62441,62549,62579,62849,63080,63185,63301,63365,63505,63520,64356,64704,64789,64824,65045,65445,65522,65663,65747,66074,66109,66663,66920,66925,66988,67115,67567,67613,67861,68167,68413,68806,69275,69779,70225,70647,70672,70912,71052,71196,71473,71503,71616,71650,71856,71901,72057,72109,72445,72488,72527,72771,72915,73225,73324,73451,73633,74174,74249,74296,74346,74417,74447,74675,74752,74796,75336,75394,75427,75674,75689,75840,75982,76164,76298,76306,76369,76464,76554,77222,77227,78041,78323,78437,78517,78526,78776,78839,80180,80182,80622,80639,81390,81425,81492,81606,81863,81906,82009,82473,82646,82905,83560,83606,83707,84674,84778,85188,85487,85527,85733,85802,85820,85822,85945,86853,86900,86915,86916,87359,87386,87530,87661,87676,87746,87884,88059,88475,88585,88855,88975,89107,89621,89987,90136,90468,90696,91319,91369,91732,91734,91810,91877,91942,92027,92198,92322,92399,92509,92660,92727,92781,92907,92970,93020,93114,93988,94065,94290,94307,94578,95062,95303,95306,95351,95577,95748,95817,95839,95844,95935,96028,96256,96384,96867,96875,97069,97461,97814,98009,98164,98197,98779,98903,98943,99024,99175,99205,99359,99362,99558,99591,99925,100188,100276,100328,101285,101361,101504,101599,101912,102005,102058,102373,102596,103574,103774,103907,104308,104806,104891,105129,105341,105800,105875,105925,106119,106173,106184,106453,106536,106760,106763,106943,107030,107181,107507,107840,107875
```

Pese a haber ido con cuidado, en el listado de perfles F podrían haber falsos positivos (NoF considerados F), si alguien se anima a hacer el mismo análisis, podemos comparar resultados.

Usaré abreviaciones para referirme a los siguientes concetpos:

- **F**: Perfil aparentemente Femenino. Un perfil del sitio SO.es que a primera vista podría considerarse que pertenece a una mujer. En los gráficos he usado el color verde para representarlo.
- **NoF**: Perfil aparentemente No Femenino. Un perfil del sitio SO.es que a primera vista NO podría considerarse que pertenece a una mujer. En los gráficos he usado el color rojo para representarlo.

Utilizo el término "*Aparentemente Femenino/No Femenino*" porque a parte de las apariencias no hay maneras de asegurar que un perfil de SO.es pertenece a una mujer o a un hombre; además alguien puede estar usando un perfil que no refleje su realidad (como en mi caso) y ésto puede suceder en F y NoF, por ello asumo que existe un márgen de error desconocido en ambos sentidos (F considerado NoF y viceversa).

### Apoyo y aceptación.

Voy a analizar el apoyo y aceptación de los F respecto los NoF, empezando por una de las acciones que más enervan a los usuarios y que puede relacionarse con la aceptación u hostilidad respecto al usuario, los hilos cerrados<sup>E</sup>:

[image]

Observamos que existe una diminuta tendencia a cerrar más los hilos de F (5,83% de cierre) que los hilos de NoF (5,48%), los hilos de F son cerrados el 0,35% de las veces más que los de NoF.

En la distribución de los votos<sup>F</sup>, separando por preguntas y respuestas vemos los siguientes datos:

[image]

[image]

Lo primero que debo señalar es que las diferencias en distribución de votos son tan pequeñas, que para que sean apreciables he tenido que usar escala logarítmica, teniendo en cuenta esas diminutas diferencias cabe señalar que en general la muestra de F tiene valores menos extremos que la muestra NoF, es decir: tanto en positividad como en negatividad los NoF se van al extremo, pero en los tramos que coinciden los F y los NoF, los primeros tienen (ligeramente) mejor acogida.

- En los tramos de puntuación negativa, cuando hay F suele estar más bajo que NoF.
- En los tramos de puntuación positiva, cuando hay F suele estar más alto que NoF.

Esto nos da la siguiente distribución de PIN<sup>2</sup>, separada por publicaciones cerradas y publicaciones no cerradas<sup>G</sup>:

[image]

[image]

Se puede ver que, como se veía anteriormente, existe una tendencia a tratar las publicaciones de F con menor dureza y con mayor positividad que a las publicaciones de NoF, aún dentro de las publicaciones con mayor negatividad (las publicaciones cerradas) existe una mayor tendencia a ignorar o votar positivamente la publicación en F que en NoF.

Si tenemos en cuenta otras métricas que reflejan la relevancia, acogida y PIN de los perfiles:

[image]

Vemos que la tendencia de acoger mejor, tratar con más amabilidad y menos negatividad a los F se mantiene, salvo en las preguntas cerradas:

- Un F tiene más probabilidad de que su pregunta sea respondida (81,39%) que un NoF (76,65%).
- Responder en una pregunta de F tiene más probabilidad de ser aceptada (49,62%) que responder en una pregunta de NoF (42,71%).
- Si un F responde, es más probable que le acepten la respuesta (34,53%) que si responde un NoF (33,07%).

Pero las diferencias siguen siendo más bien pequeñas.

## Conclusión.

No he podido apreciar una menor relevancia o menor apoyo en los F respecto a los NoF, al contrario: he notado un muy ligero aumento del apoyo y aceptación, ésto puede deberse a:

#### El apoyo y aceptación del F es fruto del [sexismo benevolente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambivalent_sexism).

Una de las manifestaciones del sexismo benevolente es la idealización de las mujeres, poniéndolas en un pedestal («*men's dependence on women is what fuels benevolently sexist attitudes, leading to idolization and the placing of women on a pedestal*» —[Glick and Fiske](http://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0022-3514.70.3.491)—); este efecto se podría manifestar de forma que las publicaciones con F fuesen juzgadas con menos dureza o que frente a publicaciones similares se escogiese apoyar más la del F frente a la del NoF.

Ésta explicación se ajusta a mis observaciones, y el efecto del sexismo benevolente también ha sido observado en otros contextos:

- [Un estidio Australiano usando *currículos ciegos*](https://pmc.gov.au/sites/default/files/publications/BETA-report-going-blind-to-see-more%20clearly.pdf) descubrió que cuando se eliminan los datos personales de los CV (género, etnicidad, edad, etc...) las posibilidades de contratar a una mujer bajaban ligeramente respecto a cuando los mismos datos estaban presentes.

#### No ha habido ninguna voluntad de menospreciar los F por pertenecer a mujeres.

Dada que diferencia en apoyo y aceptación entre F y NoF es pequeña se podría considerar que sus publicaciones gustan *per se*, sin que el hecho de que sea un F o un NoF afecte en nada.

---

En mi opinión, parece que tener un F o un NoF no afecta al valor que se le da a las intervenciones de dicho perfil o en caso de afectar, lo hace de manera ligeramente positiva hacia un F.

Respecto a situaciones de hostilidad y acoso, no puedo hacer ninguna valoración pues no tengo contacto con esos perfiles.

---

1. Es una corta selección de artículos usando Google con búsquedas como "stem is hostile to women" o "mujeres en tecnología", podéis ver más artículos del tema haciendo búsquedas parecidas.
2. Positividad, Indiferencia, Negatividad (PIN): la positividad se calcula sumando toda la puntuación positiva de las publicaciones. La indiferencia se calcula contando todas las publicaciones que tuvieron 0 votos. La negatividad se calcula sumando toda la puntuación negativa de las publicaciones.

---

- E: Preguntas cerradas y no cerradas para F y NoF:

  ```
  SELECT
    'Total' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL THEN 1 END) NoCerrados,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) Cerrados
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1
  UNION
  SELECT
    'F' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL THEN 1 END) NoCerrados,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) Cerrados
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1 AND
    OwnerUserId IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  UNION
  SELECT
    'NoF' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL THEN 1 END) NoCerrados,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) Cerrados
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1 AND
    OwnerUserId NOT IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  ```
- F: Distribución de votos en F y NoF.

  ```
  SELECT
    'Total' Grupo,
    Score,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 1 THEN 1 END) Preguntas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) Respuestas
  FROM
    Posts
  GROUP BY
    Score
  UNION
  SELECT
    'F' Grupo,
    Score,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 1 THEN 1 END) Preguntas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) Respuestas
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    OwnerUserId IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  GROUP BY
    Score
  UNION
  SELECT
    'NoF' Grupo,
    Score,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 1 THEN 1 END) Preguntas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PostTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) Respuestas
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    OwnerUserId NOT IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  GROUP BY
    Score
  ```
- G: PIN de publicaciones F y NoF:

  ```
  SELECT
    'Total' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(Score) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN SCORE END) Positividad,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 0 THEN 1 END) Indiferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score < 0 THEN SCORE END) Negatividad
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    ClosedDate IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT
    'F' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(Score) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN SCORE END) Positividad,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 0 THEN 1 END) Indiferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score < 0 THEN SCORE END) Negatividad
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    ClosedDate IS NULL AND
    OwnerUserId IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  UNION
  SELECT
    'NoF' Grupo,
    COUNT(Id) Posts,
    SUM(Score) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN SCORE END) Positividad,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 0 THEN 1 END) Indiferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score < 0 THEN SCORE END) Negatividad
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    ClosedDate IS NULL AND
    OwnerUserId NOT IN( ... Listado de F ... )
  ```

---

Pueden verse datos adicionales en [ésta hoja de cálculo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_YwG-Hsjd8BgZIqCPml7lxH2zBzE4qf6hw5Wrsr8tc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Uau, interesantísima iniciativa. Yo siempre he pensado que el mayor impacto que tiene el nombre y el género es en el número de visitas que recibes en tu perfil.

Comment: Bunea iniciativa , bueno yo jamas he  decriminado a las mujeres programadoras que conozco Joder creo que algunas son mejores  que yo y amo aprender de ellas :P yo siempre he dicho que si tenemos el  mismo interes por el sector y nos ayudamos no importa su genero aunque ami no me importa de que sector,religion,etc son las personas solosi  son buenas personas :)

Comment: opino que el titulo quedaria mejor de esta manera : " Aceptación, apoyo y positividad de las publicaciones hechas por mujeres en StackOverflow en español"

Comment: Me acabo de enterar que existe una API de Stack Exchange, pero no la sé manejar muy bien. Dejo el enlace: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!40CfKTwP5o8lFS3Xb&site=es.stackoverflow