# ¿De verdad pensáis que las herramientas y la moderación están funcionando?

Tags: discusión, voto-serial

Esta es mi tercera y última publicación en Meta (al menos por un largo tiempo).

En todas básicamente decía lo mismo: **las herramientas no se están utilizando para hacer cumplir las normas y existe una tendencia de empobrecimiento en la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio**.

En las dos preguntas anteriores he recibido en general respuestas de que todo va bien y que no hay que preocuparse.

También explicaba que me refería a la etiqueta de Java pues es ya la única que revisaba (por gusto personal).

Un poco antes de publicar esta pregunta he visto en el chat lo siguiente:

- hmmm Python es tuya, Java no me animo porque tiene una comunidad muy rompe
  hue.... JavaScript quizás - [hace 6h por Mariano](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=36224102#36224102)
- jaja. Yo también evitó Java como si fuera la peste. - [hace 6h por  toledano](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=36224108#36224108)
- Yo ignoro la etiqueta y omito votar sus preguntas... aunque confieso que me
  encantan las batallas de la luna llena... por puro morbo. - [hace 5h por 
  toledano](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=36224149#36224149)
- Ayer ya me fui a casa preocupado porque hubo 10 preguntas seguidas que eran ... uf - [hace 1h por lois6b](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=36226447#36226447)
- no se . ultimamente me afectann mas las publicaciones nuevas. van corriendo a preguntar sin molestarse en saber como es este sitio - [hace 19m por lois6b](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=36226921#36226921)

Lo cual me hace pensar que efectivamente algo pasa con esa etiqueta. Desde mi punto de vista se cumple la profecía de [este blog](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) que se puede encontrar en las [FAQ de SOes meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/19623) como lectura recomendada. Básicamente dice que lo primero que se debe aclarar es: Ok, tienes un problema => **¿Qué has intentado?**. De lo contrario se ganarán usuarios perezosos que ahuyentarán por desgaste a los usuarios que de verdad aportan contenido deseado.

Todos los esfuerzos que he tenido por intentar cambiar esta tendencia me han salido por la culata. Puede que me haya explicado mal o que no sea popular. No sé, incluso **hubiera seguido colaborando porque respeto la opinión mayoritaria y lo único que pedía era un cambio en las normas que no se cumplen y un criterio más objetivo de votación para ganar en coherencia, evitar ruido y ganar usuarios perezosos (no inexpertos, nadie nace sabiendo, pero sí debe haber ganas por aprender) y no perder colaboradores útiles**.

Pero lo que no estoy dispuesto a soportar es que si no se comparten opiniones se pase inmediatamente a ataques personales ni ser víctima del voto serial negativo. He reportado mi caso y no he tenido respuesta durante más de una semana. Además he tenido más de 20 votos negativos, pero no se trata de marcar una publicación confusa o que es poco útil (como marcan las etiquetas de voto negativo), se trata de un voto para penalizar el comportamiento de una persona, no la calidad de una publicación.

Algunos saben el origen de este caso particular (algunos me apoyaron y se lo agradezco). Para el resto no hace falta explicar el hecho en sí. Ya no quiero arreglar nada de aquello. Lo único que quiero decir es que las herramientas fallan y la moderación escasea (¿hacen falta más moderadores?) en base a los siguientes puntos:

1. No se cumplen las normas del sitio (como responder a preguntas no válidas) y a quien intenta hacer cumplirlas se le trata de rígido o agresivo.
2. No hay intención por esforzarse realmente en hacer que se cumplan porque como hay muchos usuarios siempre van a pasar cosas parecidas y no se puede hacer nada (escasez de colaboración).
3. **Las diferencias de opinión algunos se las toman a lo personal y tratan de ofender o ridiculizar por ello**.
4. **Se vota no en base a la calidad de las publicaciones, sino para ganar usuarios con privilegios rápido para hacer "crecer" el sitio y hay mucho voto por motivos personales**.
5. **Cuando se reportan los dos últimos casos (al menos 5 reportes) no se obtiene ninguna respuesta (hace ya una semana del primer reporte) aún siguiendo todas las normas del FAQ.**

No digo que todo sea así, pero sí que cada vez es más frecuente. Tampoco digo que nadie lo haga. Usuarios como @Mariano, @ArtEze, @lois6b, @fedorqui, @Lamak, @sstan, @LuiggiMendoza y otros que me dejo olvidados (perdonad) sé que dedican mucho esfuerzo al sitio y lo que hay es gracias a ellos. Os echaré de menos.

Pero, por lo anterior, estaré ausente un largo tiempo de SOes esperando que cambie o me apañaré como siempre con SO, ya que entré en este sitio por invitación para ayudar. Si tengo que aguantar en España la corrupción del gobierno, la tibieza de los jueces y la tiranía de lo políticamente correcto porque no voy a irme a vivir a otro país con problemas parecidos, lo soportaré. Si tengo que aguantarlo en un sitio web, es tan fácil como no usarlo.

Espero que algún día vean la tendencia que digo (en Java) y el resto también quiera de verdad observar las normas y tomar medidas para remediarlo, en vez de mirar al contador de visitas, el de reputación u otras métricas que digan que el sitio va mejor (no hay que creer sólo a los números).

Comment: Antes que nada destacar que me sabe muy mal si realmente te vas del sitio, date un tiempo y vuelve, solo deja que las cosas se enfrien un poco. Queria poner eso si que comentas que " He reportado mi caso y no he tenido respuesta durante más de una semana." --> Respondi a tu reporte hace 2 o 3 dias, hice una investigacion a fondo y no existe voto serial alguno. Lo que hay son muchos votos negativos de usuarios individualmente sin relacion alguna en cuanto a cuentas. No has sido victima de voto serial, te lo aseguro, me tire un buen rato investigando y NADA lo indica.

Comment: Creo que yo incumplo el primer punto. A veces he respondido a preguntas que estaban mal hechas o mostraban una evidente pereza del OP. En general trato de usar los comentarios para enriquecer la pregunta, pero otras veces respondo haciendo yo mismo los supuestos. Desde ese punto de vista ¿Dónde está realmente el límite para definir que una pregunta está mal hecha?

Comment: @amenadiel el limite está en el cierre. si 5 personas consideran que está mal hecha, se cierra.

Comment: Y qué pasa si uno responde y luego la cierran? Soy culpable retroactivamente por andar respondiendo a base de supuestos? Mea culpa.

Comment: Si están funcionando. Incluso en [tag:java]. En el supuesto caso, no concediendo, que tu caso sea cierto, sería una excepción y no la norma. Y ojalá que cuando regreses los problemas en esa comunidad hayan desaparecido...

Comment: Es una lástima cuando un usuario que brinda buenos aportes comenta que deja el sitio y lo hace por insatisfacción. Yo te recomendaría que vuelvas luego de unos días que hayas despejado tu mente.

Comment: @MiquelColl confío en que lo has revisado, pero seguro que es difícil detectarlo si no lo hace el script. No acostumbro a recibir votos negativos. Recibir 20 en una publicación puedo entenderlo, aunque creo que es por mal uso de los votos. Recibir en un día 3 votos negativos en 3 preguntas distintas durante la conexión de un usuario que coincide respondiendo las 3 y que me está insultando en otras, eso no me parece coincidencia. Por otro lado, no he recibido ninguna resolución del reporte de los votos ni de los insultos. Si no se ven efectos de la moderación es como si no hubiera.

Comment: @amenadiel mira el [comentario de Mariano](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36226971#36226971) al respecto de "Y qué pasa si uno responde y luego la cierran?"

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza a mi también me molesta tener que dejarlo, pero estoy convencido de que volverá a pasar. No es por una discusión, yo he discutido contigo y te aprecio. He aprendido del sitio, pero hace meses había buenos usuarios que ya no están, se nota y es por lo que dice el blog que he dejado enlace en la pregunta: si llenas el sitio de usuarios perezosos (dame el código) los buenos se van y los rapiñadores de reputación se cansarán cuando vean que ya no ganan tanto. Si encima se permiten ataques personales y no pasa nada, esto **Volverá a pasar**.

Comment: Me apena leer que lanzas la toalla, Awes0meM4n. Como en todo, uno debe organizarse y luego luchar. Creo que esa organización existe, pero necesita perfilarse para ir todos a una. Incluso [so], con sus ocho años de vida, sigue bajo el peligro de dejarse arrastrar por la combinación de preguntones perezosos y respondones demasiado preocupados por la reputación. Perseveremos en el intento con el convencimiento de que dar ejemplo es lo que mejor podemos dejar.

Comment: En cuanto al voto serial, nótese que por definición consiste en que una única persona vote masivamente a otra persona. No es este el caso, pues recibiste negativos en una pregunta/respuesta, pero no en el resto. Por tanto, es simplemente un caso de voto masivo por parte de muchos usuarios en desacuerdo con algo. [¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/663/83)

Comment: @fedorqui Como puse en mi comentario anterior, fueron 3 votos, en 3 preguntas distintas, en un día, con un usuario que también está en las tres y que me estaba atacando personalmente en ese momento. Si para llamarlo voto serial 3 no es suficiente y hacen falta 10 o más, llámalo de otra forma, pero el espíritu es el mismo. Como decía no es por tener 20 negativos en la misma. Por otra parte los ataques personales son públicos y patentes, incluso a más personas, no sólo a mí. He visto antes a otros usuarios suspendidos una semana por menos. Dejar que eso pase me parece una falta de moderación.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a votos en Meta o en el sitio principal? Nótese que para que salte una alarma de voto serial, este debe ser sustancial. 3 votos no se pueden considerar como tal. Es molesto, lo sé, pero creo que es un detalle de los que colman el vaso, no el motivo principal de que hayas tomado esta decisión. Sugeriría separar unas cosas de las otras, ver quién/cuánta gente usa el sitio correctamente, por un lado, y cuánta no. Yo recibo votos negativos de vez en cuando y me fastidia, claro está, pero si la respuesta es buena es cuestión de tiempo que se recuperen.

Comment: @fedorqui me refiero al sitio principal. Yo también he recibido algún voto en otros momentos de esos que ni sabes porqué. Pero es que no se trata de 3 votos. Se trata de que si cualquiera puede hacer (por ejemplo votar) y **decir** lo que quiera contra una persona y no pasa nada por parte de la moderación y la comunidad parece que lo apoya por otros votos, yo no voy a seguir perdiendo el tiempo y ganando cabreos. Debe ser que me explico muy mal. Lo que digo es que **las herramientas no están funcionando porque cada vez estas cosas pasan y pasarán más a menudo y no hay respuesta contra ellas**.

Comment: Entiendo que reportaste comentarios. En tal caso, sugiero que abras preguntas específicas del tipo: ¿por qué este comentario [ lo pones aquí ] no fue eliminado después de que lo reportara como [ irrespetuoso u ofensivo / no constructivo / ...]. Así podremos dar más claridad al asunto. Este tipo de preguntas son muy frecuentes en Meta de [so] y ayudan a auditar y entender cómo gestionan estas situaciones los moderadores.

Comment: Yo también me fui varios meses por esos motivos y por otros tantos más, finalmente decidí volver pero a hacer un aporte mucho menor y con menos corazón, y aquí sigo, inconforme con muchas cosas pero aportando algunos granos de arena, aunque más pequeños que al comienzo, esperando que algún día mejore es.SO

Comment: @Shaz precisamente tu eras uno de los que estabas a diario, o casi, cuando empece y se te hecha de menos... Si comparas las curvas de reputación de nosotros dos se ve como se aplana practicamente a la vez XD

Comment: Tristemente, estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tu publicación. Empecé en verano si no recuerdo mal y estuve unos meses muy activo (hasta diciembre más o menos), conectandome practicamente a diario. Sin embargo, vi que cada vez el comportamiento de los usuarios cambiaba y que se iniciaba una escalada de preguntas vagas y usuarios que les seguían el juego. De hecho, puede que en alguna pecara yo también y respondiera. Después de reportar y eliminar muchas preguntas al respecto, y dejar muchos comentarios, decidí marcharme por unos meses, metiéndome de vez en cuando pero para nada como antes.

Comment: He decidido volver, o al menos estar más activo por aquí, y espero no equivocarme. Me gustaría poder ver que las cosas han cambiado y hacer de este sitio un sitio respetable y que pueda ser útil al resto de usuarios. Y no solo a ellos, si no a mí también, porque hay usuarios que me han ayudado mucho en los meses que estuve activo a aprender y sobre todo a no dejar de hacerlo. Usuarios que se preocupan por el sitio como tú son los que hacen falta para no dejar caer un foro que puede brindar muchas posibilidades y puede ser útil a tantísimas personas.

Answer (score 19):

Esto no es una respuesta, pero les cuento sobre mi experiencia personal.

Tengo casi 40 años. Hace 15 años fundé un sitio de hardware cuyo foro llegó a tener algo así como 500.000 usuarios y 1000 threads diarios. Hace 5 perdí definitivamente ese sitio por una mala jugada que me hizo uno de mis socios pero eso es otra historia.

El tema es el siguiente: en un principio la filosofía de ese foro era la automoderación. Los moderadores existían para mover o fusionar threads, plantear temas de discusión, incentivar la participación, etc. Y eran, obviamente, escogidos de entre los mismos usuarios por mostrar alto compromiso, conocimiento y criterio.

Pasó que a medida que el foro fue creciendo, fueron apareciendo otros fenómenos.

Teníamos un subforo de compraventa y llegó un punto en que se ofrecieron artículos robados y la policía me citó a declarar. Empezamos a pedir factura de todo lo que se vendía, con la consiguiente recarga para los moderadores. Tuvimos que hacer threads de arbitraje para las disputas entre compradores y vendedores. Tuvimos que hacer un plugin de reputación para que cada usuario tuviese un hilo en donde otros opinaban, y luego un plugin al plugin para comprobar que no fuese un testimonio falso.

Tuvimos trolls, spammers, representantes de marcas posando como usuarios, tuvimos amenazas, tuvimos lazos de amistad que se forjaron ahí y perduraron, y hasta tuvimos dos matrimonios entre usuarios y usuarias que se conocieron en el foro.

Tuvimos auspiciadores y nos invitaron a ferias internacionales de hardware con todos los gastos pagados. Y tuvimos mil y un dolores de cabeza escalando el hardware y software para permitir servir el sitio de manera estable. Junto con los auspiciadores y la venta de publicidad también vino la ambición de los que veían el sitio como un negocio, e indirectamente eso terminó con mi salida hace ya 5 años.

No sé adonde quería llegar con esta historia, pero creo que la lección es que, a medida que una comunidad crece, no es trivial dirigirla, en el sentido de orientarla en una dirección definida. Es como pastorear un rebaño de 500.000 ovejas esperando que se muevan al unísono.

Los sitios y sus comunidades se comportan como un organismo multicelular. Cada sitio tiene sus reglas y sus usuarios, pero su carácter es único y las primeras no condicionan el resultado final.

Comment: Muy interesante, gracias por compartir.

Comment: Interesante experiencia, agradezco la compartas, saludos.

Comment: Comparto tu punto de vista. He aquí mi respuesta a esta publicación: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/24/nuestra-comunidad-funciona/

Comment: al principio pense "a donde quiere llegar?" pero es un excelente punto no se puede "pastorear un rebaño de 500.000 ovejas esperando que se muevan al unísono."

Comment: Que mal que hayas perdido tu sitio :( por la ayuda que nos brindas pareces una persona buena, pero bueno ¿que se le hace?. Gracias por compartir tu opinión.

Answer (score 12):

**Lo primero:** No te vayas :(

Por hacer este post eres uno de esos usuarios que mencionas que se esfuerzan por este sitio. Necesitamos más gente asi, no menos.

Respecto a lo que dices, estoy muy de acuerdo.

> "1. No se cumplen las normas del sitio (como responder a preguntas no válidas) y el que intenta hacer cumplirlas se le trata de rígido o agresivo."

Estuve a punto de hacer una pregunta en Meta al respecto, solo para las respuestas en preguntas que es **obvio** que se van a cerrar.

Muchos usuarios responden a preguntas que no deseamos aqui (por el momento) como discusiones de opinion general, preguntas que solo un adivino puede contestar (si, a veces lo que pregunta está claro, pero no de la manera en que lo expresa y una edicion es más que necesaria) , o gente que ni intenta las cosas y pretende que alguien le conteste (y obtiene respuesta porque siempre hay alguien deseoso de ayudar y/o ganar reputación).

En muchas respuestas de esas he comentado:

> "No es conveniente responder ya que el autor no ha publicado su codigo, lo que ha intentado ni los errores que ha tenido. Te recomiendo que la borres y cuando el autor edite su pregunta, puedes pulsar en *Recuperar*. Si la dejas, y has acertado con el problema del usuario, no se va a molestar en editar su pregunta, va a coger **tu** codigo y la proxima vez tampoco se esforzará, ya que *ya habrá alguien que me responda*"

Y me contestan que solo quieren ayudar, y yo lo entiendo pero **a veces ayudar a una persona no es ayudar al sitio**. Y sin un buen sitio no se podrá ayudar a las personas.

A veces si que me siento como "el malo" cuando a un usuario nuevo le digo lo anterior o que " esta respuesta no es una respuesta si no un comentario" o "por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir la informacion, no la pongas en los comentarios".

---

> "Si tengo que aguantarlo en un sitio web, es tan fácil como no usarlo."

Si, pero tú puedes cambiar más este sitio de lo que puedes cambiar España (siguiendo tu ejemplo).

A veces, siento que podria rendirme (como en los comentarios que hice en el chat y mencionas en tu pregunta). Pero lo que quiero es que ésto mejore y pienso que yendome no mejoria.

Mariano me dijo:

> " Puede ser frustrante, pero si realmente te está empezando a molestar, recordá que podés tomarte unos días ignorándolas, y volver más adelante con una mente fresca" .

Unas *vacaciones* están bien para dejar a un lado lo malo y volver fresco como una lechuga. Pero no rendirse.

<sub>Hasta aquí mi opinión, puede que luego vuelva y añada más opinión sobre otros puntos de tu pregunta</sub>

Comment: Excelente opinión, the agradezco el refrescarnos con lo dicho.  Es difícil esto de construir una comunidad pero así aprendemos.  Yo también le sugiero al OP que se tome unos días para refrescarse.  Necesitamos a más gente como él para crecer sanamente.

Answer (score 1):

**No te vayas**, es lo que puedo decir, cada aporte de los miembros de la comunidad es necesario y valioso para la comunidad.

Quisiera responder a algunos puntos:

> 1. No se cumplen las normas del sitio (como responder a preguntas no
>      válidas) y el que intenta hacer cumplirlas se le trata de rígido o
>      agresivo.

Mi opinión es que *no todo es blanco o negro*; con esto quiero decir que son muchos los usuarios nuevos quienes realmente no toman el recorrido del sitio y solo buscan "una respuesta inmediata - sin relacionarse con el sitio" y hay unos pocos usuarios *(ya con cierta reputación)* quienes buscan mas reputación.

**tl;dr**: no todos los usuario son así, aquellos pocos que puedan existir son "tóxicos" = no le sigas el juego, vota/reporta y continúa tu camino.

No he tenido "hasta el momento" algún roce con otros usuarios, pero, en caso de presentarse, simplemente respondo según las normas de "[ser amable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)" y sigo adelante.

---

> ...(escasez de colaboración).

Si, se necesitan mas moderadores y otros usuarios con la reputación suficiente para que tengan acceso a las funcionalidades requeridas para la "administración de calidad" del sitio y que además aporten de diferentes maneras al sito.

---

> Las diferencias de opinión algunos se lo toman a los personal y tratan
>   de ofender o ridiculizar por ello.

Pienso que esto se debe a dos factores:

- *Cada persona es diferente*
- *No muchos leen la guía de (ser amable)*.

Con esto, repito: ***no le sigas el juego, vota/reporta y continúa tu camino.***

Tómate tu tiempo, el que necesites, pero te invito a reconsiderar: ¿por qué te uniste y decidiste formar parte de esta comunidad, tu comunidad?.

Respetaré cualquier decisión que tomes, pero me gustaría que tomes en cuenta lo que he escrito (y repito :D ):

> ***no le sigas el juego, vota/reporta y continúa tu camino.***

Créeme, esto me ha salvado de muchos dolores de cabeza y malestar no solo en mi entorno laboral, sino en el entorno personal.

Comment: Faltan moderadores en el sentido de usuarios con permisos de moderación, o se refiere a que faltan moderadores con permisos especiales como LuiggiMendoza?

Comment: @amenadiel mas usuarios con permisos de moderación _(y si así lo merecen)_, pueden volverse moderadores con permisos especiales. También el sitio necesita usuarios con conocimientos en lenguajes, frameworks y demás elementos tecnológicos. Yo, por ejemplo, reviso algunas veces Q&A de C# y HTML, pero mis aportes son principalmente ediciones. Hay otros usuarios que han aportado mucho valor al sitio, pero hay nuevas preguntas (mercadolibre) que personalmente evito = soporte.