# Como reportar persona que siempre pone puntaje malo sea cual sea la pregunta

Tags: discusión, votos, votos-negativos, voto-serial

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se debe hacer para bloquear persona que siempre pone mis peguntas en -1 sea cual sea la pregunta y pone comentarios sin sentido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver arriba tenia **+22**  ahora    **+14** me ponen mas de **15** preguntas en **-1**

Comment: En donde tienes ese problema y cual seria el usuario ?¿

Comment: No veo que en el sitio tengas esos problemas, por favor especifica.

Comment: Cada vez que pongo una pregunta, al minuto ya tiene un -1   es este el usuario user:107224,  si verifican mis preguntas van a ver que siempre me pone  -1 gracias, el problema es en es.stackoverflow

Comment: Mmm bueno los votos son anónimos por lo que no es posible estar al 100% seguro de que se trate de ese usuario, en todo caso una vez que un moderador vea esta publicación me imagino le echará un ojo, aunque según veo tus preguntas solo encontré unas 3 con  `-1` así a la rápida pero no parecen estar muy seguidas que digamos. Pero bueno espero algún moderador te ayude con este problema. ;)

Comment: No veo donde haya correlación del usuario que mencionas, y los -1. Menos comentarios sin sentido como para decir que X persona te targetea.

Comment: es por que cada vez que me pone un -1 otro amigo le pone  un  + 1 para poder que no descarten mi pregunta  y ese - 1 no quede en la pregunta

Comment: Primero, no se ve que tengas tantos votos en contra, segundo, no hay correlación entre lo que dices y el usuario mencionado, tercero, si dan -1 es por algo, y el sistema es regulado. SO no permite que alguien ande abusando de negativear... de todos modos podrías esperar a un mod a ver que dice el.

Comment: Si miran el historial una vez me puso mas de  15 preguntas  en -1, y el sistema vio y me devolvió el puntaje.

Comment: Por eso, no deberías preocuparte, dado que el sistema se encarga de eso. Además, para venir a "acusar" ven con las pruebas listas, no esperes que busquen el problema, facilita el trabajo a los demás, para no tener que estar en este ven y voy de preguntas que debería ser parte de la publicacion.

Comment: Bueno en fin no se entonces, pero lo que digo es verdad, siempre trata de dañarme las preguntas.

Comment: @Excorpion eso no es justo... por que en teoría nadie sabe que parámetro usa el Sistema para determinar abuso ... si yo hago un post diario (durante 1 año) y un ocioso me vota una vez al día negativo el sistema no lo detectara como abuso... pero tampoco es justo... ahora como es un solo usuario el afectado dudo que algún MOD le vaya a prestar la atención que se merece...

Comment: Acaban de contar que el sistema devuelve los puntos... wtf tu ?

Comment: Es decir, en un día  puso en negativo a 15 preguntas mías y se me bajo el puntaje a 100, luego de unos días el sistema detecto que era spam y  me devolvió a dar el puntaje

Comment: Yo pienso que la frase: *seria interesante que cerraras un poquito la boca* no es respetuosa. Se pide respeto sin dar respeto. Tambien la frase *Entonces callate la boca*

Comment: @eyllanesc nunca vi el comentario me entere por el otro POST que abriste en META. tu sugiero que cuando es asi... reportes por los canales que ha destinado el sitio: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3gY0.png)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/qu%c3%a9-es-el-voto-serial-y-c%c3%b3mo-me-afecta)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Siii, ¿pero cuando pasa eso continuamente que pasa? es decir ya ha pasado varias veces, me devuelven el puntaje pero entonces esto va seguir así siempre, me bajan el puntaje me lo suben otra vez  y así sucesivamente, raro eso.

Comment: Hackerman: como se explica en la documentación enlazada, si va a más los moderadores pueden investigarlo. Crea un reporte y ellos podrán investigar e incluso penalizar al hipotético tergiversador de votos.

Comment: @Hackerman Si el sistema automáticamente está recuperándote los puntos perdidos, no deberías por que preocuparte. Se que lo que buscas es una sanción directa al sujeto, pero solo va en los reportes que comiences a hacer.

Comment: Bueno gracias, muchachos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para reportar un usuario

1. selecciona una de sus publicaciones
2. haz clic en el enlace reportar
3. selecciona la opción **se necesita la intervención de un moderador**
4. indica de forma breve pero clara la situación y envíala.

Reitero, deberás ser claro con respecto al o que te llevado a hacer el reporte. Si esto ha sido derivado de algún comentario del usuario en cuestión sería muy útil el enlaces a este o bien a la publicación en la que lo hizo.

Con respecto a bloquear a un usuario como se haría en una aplicación típica de chat o de redes sociales , esto no es posible pues los sitios de SE tratan sobre contenido no sobre las relaciones entre los usuarios.

Comment: @Hackerman gbianchi no va a recibir notificación por la mención del comentario previo porque no a editado esta publicación ni ha comentado en la misma.