# ¿Es adecuado este tipo de comentarios de un usuario, y más si es un moderador?

Tags: discusión

En SO es un ambiente donde debe primar es el respeto, y los moderadores son clave ya que tienen muchos poderes por lo que deberian dar el ejemplo(no digo que los demás usuarios no deban de tenerlo).

Yo suelo tener días duros y cuando no me gusta alguna actitud de otro usuario y considero que mi respuesta va a ser irrespetuosa entonces prefiero alejarme ya que asi sigo cumpliendo las reglas de buena conducta que se enfatiza en esta comunidad.

El problema es que veo que el moderador gbianghi ha tenido este tipo de actitudes muchas veces por lo que estoy dudando de su capacidad para ser un moderador. Como muestra de lo que señalo esta el siguiente [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5233/como-reportar-persona-que-siempre-pone-puntaje-malo-sea-cual-sea-la-pregunta#comment22692_5233):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que existen mejores formas de señalarle a un usuario cuando debe señalar algo o no.

Comment: Punto y aparte de si es adecuado o no, este tipo de publicaciones no son adecuadas. Véase [¿Qué hago si veo a alguien haciendo algo malo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) y si quieres algo más específco [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/289691)

Comment: @Rubén En el último post que enlazas señala: *Make a post on the relevant per-site meta regarding the action taken, which will allow the community to discuss it.* Y justamente esa es mi intención: discutir ese asunto.

Comment: Esto parece más un ataque personal que una pregunta seria. No comparto las malas actitudes o formas, pero mucho menos comparto este tipo de publicaciones. ¿Qué edad crees que tenemos?

Comment: @MauricioContreras 1. ¿A qué ataque te refieres? Mi intención es discutir si este tipo de actitudes se deben aceptar de un moderador en SO dentro del entorno de SO 2. No sé que edad tienes pero para ser parte de SO debes tener al menos 13 años.

Comment: @eyllanesc La frase que citas la has sacado de contexto, como mínimo deberías haber incluido la primer línea "If you have a dispute with a diamond moderator, your options are:..."  pero bueno, cada quien según sus posibilidades.

Comment: @Rubén Es que esa tipo de acción de ese usuario no es nueva, ya es reiterativa. Parece que ya no tiene la paciencia de manejar ese tipo de situaciones donde el usuario no puede tener la razón, pero hay maneras adecuadas de señalarlo sino nos convertiremos en una copia de FB o Twitter. Mi principal motivo de gustarme el sitio es que las discusiones son alturadas y con mucho respeto, y el ejemplo de ello son los moderadores que siempre merecen mi respeto.

Comment: La intención podría ser buena pero la ejecución no es coherente con lo que mencionas.

Comment: @Rubén ¿entonces qué debo/debí hacer en tu opinión?

Comment: Lo que indica el primer enlace que te dejé en mi primer comentario. Opción 1, reportar, opción 2, contactar a los moderadores, cada sitio tiene al menos tres moderadores, opción 3 ponerte en contacto directamente con el equipo de gerentes de comunidad.

Comment: Elegiste un mal ejemplo. Podríamos alegar que es un comentario rudo pero merecido.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ningún comentario rudo es merecido en el entorno de SO. Aqui tenemos un código de conducta.

Comment: Puestos a opinar, yo creo que ese usuario se merecia el comentario de gbianchi y entiendo su postura

Comment: @Marc Yo no pienso que ningun usuario  merezca un trato rudo por parte de nadie. Alli se rompe la línea del respeto, que pienso que es una de las principales virtudes de SO.

Comment: Lo que paso fue sencillamente que el moderador perdió la paciencia con un usuario difícil, yo creo q gbianchi es un buen moderador, de hecho es al que siempre veo mas activo, y en varias ocasiones he acudido a el por chats privados. La respuesta de gbianchi debió ser igual de contundente, pero mas diplomática.

Comment: en cuanto a este post en particular, estoy en desacuerdo, este post debio ser un email mio a SE, la comunidad no tiene nada que hacer o que ver, con la relación y comunicacion que establesca un moderador con un usuario.

Comment: @eyllanesc Viendo el comentario que hay, el que empezó con faltadas es otro usuario que dijo: `dudo que algún MOD le vaya a prestar la atención que se merece` , cualquier persona con ese cargo puede sentirse atacada con ese comentario y creo que actuó en consecuencia a esto

Comment: @Marc Eso se llama justificar la rudeza, a mi muchas veces me han dicho cosas peores pero yo simplemente sigo mi camino. La rudeza no es justificable, me da un poco de pena que muchos usuarios puedan soportar la rudeza porque el usuario contribuye mucho al sitio pero yo no.

Answer (score 11):

Hay usuarios muy majos, muy simpáticos y muy todo. También los hay pesados, que van a por ti o que simplemente se aburren. Eso lo sufre todo el mundo, tanto los usuarios normales como los moderadores.

Para los usuarios normales el comportamiento que se recomienda siempre es el de "flag and move on". Es decir "reporta y sigue con tu vida", en el sentido de poner un reporte y dejar en manos de los moderadores la resolución, sin involucrarse más.

Si es un moderador el que se siente especialmente cansado, puede que estemos pensando que el dilema es mayor. Yo creo que no, pues la recomendación siempre es la misma: delégalo en otro moderador. Es decir, si un moderador no tiene paciencia, capacidad o ganas de gestionar una situación, lo que debe hacer es dejarlo para otro moderador... y "seguir con su vida". En este caso creo que es lo que se habría tenido que hacer y que se debería hacer en adelante.

Answer (score 10):

Usualmente no doy crédito (más allá de lo que en mi opinión corresponde) a publicaciones con un sentido poco claro o que generan especulaciones o incluso que podrían catalogarse de difamatorias.

Sin embargo, debido a que me has [realizado 2 preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5235/es-adecuado-este-tipo-de-comentarios-de-un-usuario-y-m%c3%a1s-si-es-un-moderador#comment22697_5235) bastante directas sobre mi opinión plasmada en un [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5235/es-adecuado-este-tipo-de-comentarios-de-un-usuario-y-m%c3%a1s-si-es-un-moderador#comment22696_5235), he decidido darte una respuesta a ambas.

Pero antes de entrar en detalles, deseo dejar claro que mi intención es simplemente responder no sólo tu pregunta planteada (me basaré en los comentarios de Rubén, si se me permite) y responder las 2 preguntas que me has realizado personalmente. Siempre desde el respeto y tratando de no entrar en polémicas o faltas, y si de alguna manera mis opiniones ofenden, pido disculpas por adelantado y sólo puedo decir que se tome como mi opinión, como un [juicio de valor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juicio_de_valor).

**¿Es adecuado este tipo de comentarios de un usuario, y más si es un moderador?**

Creo que todos (o al menos la mayoría) estaremos de acuerdo que comentarios rudos o con un tono elevado de soberbia, agresividad, desparpajo o incluso insolencia, pueden ser interpretados como un ataque, abuso, falta de respeto, etc. No es necesario tener un diamante para soltar verborrea de este tipo, sin embargo, tener un diamante es muchas veces un arma de doble filo (no me gustaría estar en los zapatos de ninguno de nuestros moderadores, su trabajo es invaluable).

Cuando uno es padre, normalmente desarrolla un talento llamado *paciencia*, al fin y al cabo la tarea de educar a un hijo/a es una tarea que requiere toneladas de este talento. Sin embargo, hay momentos en que la paciencia se agota y es usual la aplicación de castigos y reprimendas. Muchas veces, estos castigos vienen precedidos por una gran cantidad de advertencias, ya sea en forma de pláticas o llamadas de atención, incluso alguna bofetada, palmada, colleja, lepe (o cualquier sustantivo adecuado), en aras de imponer nuevamente el orden. Cuando esto no ha sido suficiente muchas veces los padres explotamos, bien sea de forma verbal o física.

Es verdad que muchas de estas explosiones lamentablemente son desmedidas, hablamos de padres, madres, hijos e hijas en situaciones familiares complejas pero que tienen un componente de unión, confianza y respeto que debería prevalecer.

Ahora bien, tomando en cuenta esta situación, la paciencia de un moderador para advertir, aconsejar, enseñar, etc. a un usuario de la red, nunca será la misma que la que pueda tener un padre o madre con su hijo o hija. ¿Porqué habría de serlo?

Cuando un usuario, que actúa de forma polémica (no pretendo decir que sea bueno o malo) constantemente, que ha recibido infinidad de advertencias, de buena manera, o no de tan buena manera, sigue sin cambiar su actitud, va a conseguir que se le hable de forma inadecuada. Exaspera los ánimos de cualquiera, debido a su constante intransigencia.

¿Fue rudo el comentario? **SI**

¿Fue adecuada la actitud del moderador? **Tal vez si**

Y porqué digo que tal vez si, porque como expreso en mis lineas anteriores, ¿de qué otra forma se puede lidiar con un hijo descarriado?

- ¿Se le ignora? Eso es casi como darle carta blanca para que siga polemizando.
- ¿Se le sanciona con una suspensión? Eso si me parece un abuso de poder.
- ¿Se le elimina el comentario polémico? No hace mucho pedían la cabeza de un moderador de SOes por esta práctica.

Un moderador tiene siempre las de perder si se critica su acción o su inacción. Hay que tener mucha paciencia y disponer de una cantidad inagotable de buen criterio para caminar por el campo minado llamado *moderación del sitio*.

Y precisamente, hablando de la *moderación*, el usuario Rubén, bien ha sabido enlazar correctamente los vínculos a publicaciones que ayudan a mejorar la moderación del sitio.

Tu pregunta en Meta, en mi opinión muy personal, es de tipo difamatoria. El tiempo transcurrido entre el comentario que muestras (ya eliminado, y que fue realizado en otra publicación de Meta) y tu pregunta, parece indicar que no pensaste mucho antes de publicar.

Tal vez con tu comentario en dicha publicación, hubiera bastado para que el moderador en cuestión repasara sus palabras e incluso las cambiara o eliminara su propio comentario.

[image: Comentario dado por el OP en otra publicación]

Si con esto no lo hubiese hecho, lo siguiente (en mi opinión) sería comunicarme directamente con dicho moderador, argumentando mi posición y pidiendo una aclaración. Los siguientes pasos, podrían pasar por comunicarme con otro moderador, incluso con los CM del sitio si sintiera que mis dudas no han sido del todo aclaradas o si las respuestas no han sido satisfactorias. Creo que hacer un Post en Meta sobre este asunto, sería lo último que haría.

Pero estoy hablando de lo que **yo** haría, y lo haría porque en mi opinión es la forma correcta de *escalar* un asunto, ya que de lo contrario pienso que se tomaría incorrectamente mi intención.

**1. ¿A qué ataque te refieres? Mi intención es discutir si este tipo de actitudes se deben aceptar de un moderador en SO dentro del entorno de SO**

Cuando me refiero a esto como un *ataque personal* lo hago desde el punto de vista de mi apreciación personal. Si lees detenidamente mi comentario dice:

> **Esto parece** más un ataque personal ...

Nunca he dicho que **es**, sino, que parece.

¿Y porque afirmo que *parece*? Pues porque leo muchas de las publicaciones de Meta, leo muchos comentarios, y leo muchas respuestas en general.

Hace poco realizaste una [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5221/traducir-la-opci%c3%b3n-other-action-de-la-cola-primeras-preguntas) en Meta, donde catalogas de *bug* la falta de traducción de ciertas partes del sitio.

Entre los comentarios que recibes en dicha pregunta se encuentran los del moderador que has expuesto ahora en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo este:

> No es un bug... las traducciones son un trabajo colaborativo... si no queres participar, no hay problema... pero no los llamamos bugs... ahora lo traduzco....\

Este comentario, **al parecer** no te sentó bien, según lo que se desprende de tu respuesta:

> ... 1. Mi trabajo colaborativo es reportarlo, más alla no me quiero involucrar, 2. ¿A qué se llama bug dentro de SOes? De mi conocimiento muy básico bug es cualquier comportamiento no esperado por el usuario, y como usuario no esperaba que algunas partes no estén traducidos, ¿hay algo de malo con usar la palabra bug?

Nuevamente el moderador te responde, esta vez con un tono un poco más serio:

> no.. no hay nada de malo... llamalo como quieras... y por eso te dije que si no querias participar no habia problema...

Creo que lo que te parece rudo es el *llámalo como quieras*. Ojalá pudiera saber lo que piensa otra persona, pero no puedo, sólo puedo especular en base a **mi** experiencia.

Hace poco un conocido que vive en latino américa hablaba con su hijo que vive en España. Este conocido le pedía disculpas a su hijo por no haberle podido llamar con anterioridad, a lo cual el niño le responde: *no pasa nada, da igual*. Las personas que vivimos en España desde hace ya un tiempo, sabemos que esta frase no tiene ninguna connotación negativa, pero para un latino americano puede ser ofensiva. *"Da igual"* es casi equivalente a *"Me vale ver..."*.

Muchas veces, nuestro uso coloquial de la lengua o nuestra forma de expresarnos pueden causar incomodidad o molestia, sin que esto sea intencionado. Yo, ante una situación así, prefiero pedir una aclaración. Un comentario como: *"disculpa, no entiendo lo que quieres decir con ..."* expresaría mejor mi buena actitud y disposición a enmendar errores y corregirlos, que un comentario diciendo que me siento ofendido y despedirme para dejar en claro que estoy molesto:

> ... parece un poco rudo tu comentario, ojala que sea mi propia percepción ya que se vería mál que un moderador tenga ese tipo de actitudes. Adios, seguire mi camino.

Nuevamente, en mi opinión muy personal, hay un precedente, y es por ello que mi impresión es que te has tomado de forma personal un comentario dado por un moderador, en una publicación de Meta que pertenece a otro OP, y dirigido a otro usuario de la red.

Puedo entender que esta pregunta la hubiera planteado el usuario que recibió dichas palabras, ya que es el directamente afectado, los demás somos afectados de forma *indirecta*.

Pienso que lo mejor es establecer un canal de comunicación, si fuera el caso, para limar las asperezas que pudieran haber surgido por una situación totalmente casual y sin malas intenciones por parte de ambos.

Por último, tal como dejo claro en el apartado anterior, ser moderador no es una tarea fácil. Pero lo que sí es fácil es criticar su trabajo, eso es lo más sencillo del mundo. Esperar agazapado a que un moderador cometa un error es desnaturalizar y desestimar todo su trabajo. No son máquinas (aunque no puedo asegurarlo al 100%, ya que no los conozco en persona), son seres humanos, y se equivocan, como tú y como yo. Sangran igual que cualquiera, y tienen emociones. El diamante de moderación no les da sabiduría infinita, al contrario los carga con mucha responsabilidad. No seamos una piedra más en su ya pesado saco.

**2. No sé que edad tienes pero para ser parte de SO debes tener al menos 13 años.**

Gracias por la aclaración, pensaba que había niños de 5 años o menos como usuarios del sitio, o al menos ese es el público al que parece estar dirigida tu pregunta.

Como dije anteriormente, no hagamos más difícil el trabajo de los moderadores. Se supone que todos estamos en el mismo bote, y debemos remar en la misma dirección.

Armar *comidilla* por un comentario desafortunado, no es la forma correcta, (nuevamente en mi opinión) de lidiar con estas situaciones.

Independientemente de quién sea el que haya cometido el error, no se puede ir dando porras a diestra y siniestra.

Como bien mencioné, hace algún tiempo hubo quejas de un moderador, por ciertas *actitudes* que parecían evidenciar un *abuso de poder*. Más allá de si estas acusaciones eran ciertas o no, queda el sinsabor de generar *desconfianza* sobre uno de los pilares de esta comunidad: *los moderadores*.

No hay, al menos que yo conozca, un patrón de comportamiento inadecuado o impropio del moderador que has expuesto en tu pregunta. Y es por ello que no puedo tomarme seriamente tu publicación. No estamos en el kinder, preescolar, parvulario (o el sustantivo que aplique), para que se hagan acusaciones o se exponga un comentario desafortunado, de la forma en que lo has expuesto aquí. Y es que esas maneras son muy típicas (y hasta aceptables) en niveles infantiles, donde se está dando forma al ser. Pero tal como me lo has aclarado gentilmente, la mayoría de usuarios de SOes ya están formados, o están en su última etapa de formación. Por lo cual, tratarlos como niños de 5 años parece ilógico y hasta es ofensivo en cierta forma.

Una publicación como esta la puedo esperar de un usuario nuevo, sin mucho recorrido en SOes o en la red SE en general, pero viniendo de un usuario con tu experiencia me hace pensar que te lo has tomado muy personalmente.

Mi consejo, si lo aceptas, es que nunca te tomes las cosas de forma personal, nunca esperes que los demás sean perfectos y nunca critiques los errores de quien los cometa, al contrario ayúdale a que no vuelva a cometerlos.

Bastantes reprimendas he recibido por parte de los moderadores, y siempre las he tomado de buen agrado, porque entiendo que es su trabajo, no les pagan por ello y lo hacen con la mejor intención.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo: principalmente un MOD debe saber como usar las palabras al responderle a un usuario, se supone que este sitio es un entorno de colaboración, la única diferencia es que no hay plata de por medio; entonces tu le responderías esto a un compañero de trabajo o a tu líder "***llámalo como quieras... y por eso te dije que si no querías participar no había problema...***" cuando veo estos, comentario de un moderador, prefiero asumir que es un trato "regional" así suelen ser en sur américa, ha tenido una mala semana o un mal día.

Comment: pero cuando veo este actuar con un grupo de usuario o un usuario en especifico ya cualquiera persona pensaría que es algo personal ... o que le desagrada lo que esta haciendo ...

Comment: el ejemplo que usaste sobre el post en META sobre traducción, el objetivo del usuario no ha sido en ningún momento, aclarar su participación en la traducción del sitio.... el objetivo fue reportar algo que no estaba funcionando bien o que no tenia el efecto/lenguaje esperado... por que el Moderador o pudo ser otro usuario... debe argumenta " si no querías participar no había problema" que tiene que ver con que participe o no .... incluso con hacer el post esta participado...

Comment: me demore 1 hora en leer tu post y asimilarlo correctamente ... y creo que el enfoque de la pregunta es; sobre el comentario en general y no si a el le cae mal los comentarios de el Moderador...

Comment: Sinceramente, tampoco estoy de acuerdo con la manera en la que el moderador respondió. He leído las respuestas y comentarios y la mayoría dice "SO es un sitio donde el respeto es pieza clave pero, como este moderador ha ayudado tanto muchas veces que se lo podemos dejar pasar o minimizar el problema". En mi opinión, si no se tiene paciencia, se debe evitar el involucrarse, así de simple.

Comment: Se enfocaron en discutir una respuesta, y no me ayudaron con mi pregunta. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5233/como-reportar-persona-que-siempre-pone-puntaje-malo-sea-cual-sea-la-pregunta

Answer (score 8):

Voy a ser breve y a dar mi opinión.

Un usuario ataca directamente el trabajo de los moderadores con un comentario que dice:

> dudo que algún MOD le vaya a prestar la atención que se merece

Un moderador responde en consecuencia a este comentario porque probablemente se haya sentido atacado.

El que recibe todo el `'beef'` es el moderador cuando el que ha descubierto el pastel es otro.

Creo que a quien se debería reeducar es al usuario que descubrió el pastel, y creo que es él el que debería de disculparse a los moderadores por ese comentario. Si no lo hubiera hecho nada de esto habría pasado.

Answer (score 6):

Tu pregunta se centra en saber y discutir si la acción (comentario) del moderador gbianchi ha sido correcta, de adelanto voy diciendo que no, pero todo tiene una explicación.

Como bien dice Francisco Nuñes, la zona de comentarios es un lugar para dar/pedir aclaraciones, aportar a la pregunta y dar ti propia opinión. Muchas veces he visto decir a usuario que nunca te debes tomar algo de forma personal ya que sino sales perdiendo. Esto es lo que le pasó a gbianchi, se tomó el comentario como personal, habiendo 4 moderadores a los que pudo ir dirigido el comentario gbianchi decidió responder, he aquí un punto en contra.

El trabajo de un moderador es bastante sofocante y lleno de difíciles decisiones, muchas veces he hablado con gbianchi a cerca del sitio y me sorprende la tanta profesionalidad que el tiene, por ahora sigo sus consejos para ser moderador ya que quiero ser uno (aunque no lo conseguiré en un buen tiempo).

Si separamos lo que ocurre en el chat y lo que ocurre en el sitio principal puedo decir que gbianchi se ha pasado de la raya. Para mí el chat es un sitio donde puedes dialogar con los demás usuario sobre cualquier tema y poco a poco puedes ganar confianza, como por ejemplo hacerle unos memes a @Trauma, pequeñas burlas a algunos lenguajes de programación, criticar a algún plato de comida, etc. Si yo tengo en cuenta esto y como es que es la relación de Francisco y gbianchi entonces creo que el comentario es válida sabiendo como es Francisco (con esto no quiero decir que Francisco sea un usuario molesto ni nada, solo que siempre hay discusión por su muy distante punto de vista).

Algo que creo algo que también puede jugar en contra es la forma de hablar (lenguaje), no todas las palabras significan lo mismo en todas las partes del mundo, por esta razón hay que tener cuidado con la elección de palabras, es posible que una u otra vez se te haya escapado alguna palabra coloquial de tu país y que otro usuario lo interprete mal, disculpen por el ejemplo pero es lo que se me ocurrió, la palabra "concha" varía mucho según el país y dependiendo del contexto puede ser interpretado de buena o mala forma. Recuerdo muy bien que gbianchi tuvo una pequeña discusión con usuario nuevo y que por alguna razón no fue llevado a meta (como en este caso). Hubo unas palabras que causaron algo de confusión:

> [...] vete a saber [..]

En tal caso el usuario le pidió que le tuviera respeto y gbianchi le pregunto si en algún momento le falto el respeto y también acudió al chat para saber las opiniones de los demás. Por esto creo que el comentario de gbianchi se pudo mal entender por decir "cierra la boca". Si mal no recuerdo en Argentina es sería despectivo decir "cerra el @rt.." y si ese hubiese sido el comentario estaría en totalmente de acuerdo que el comentario es despectivo y vulgar. Por lo que el idioma siempre juega en contra.

Algo que destacó Muaricio Contreras y Fedorqui es que muchos de nosotros nos encontramos con miles de usuarios diferentes cada día, hace poco me encontré con un usuario que hizo una respuesta y me acusó de acoso y de impedir trasmitir el conocimiento, yo simplemente le había dicho que la pregunta no era adecuada para el sitio y se exaltó como si le hubiera dirigido a él. Cuando no puedo responder alguna pregunta siempre me gusta que alguien más lo haga para que así la pregunta sea solucionada. Lo que quiero decir es que siempre habrá algún usuario que te saque de tus cabales y puedes reaccionar de forma aberrante donde ni siquiera te da tiempo de respirar. No soy psicólogo y no me pondré ha hablar de como es que un moderador debe  de actuar cuando se le acabe la paciencia. Tal y como dijo Mauricio:

> Sin embargo, hay momentos en que la paciencia se agota y es usual la aplicación de castigos y reprimendas.

Esto le pasará hasta a un padre/madre de familia.

Últimamente en el sitio he visto muchas publicaciones "basura", de mala calidad, spam, etc. y gbianchi siempre estuvo ahí moderando el sitio, puede ser que ese día gbianchi no lo haya pasado bien y ese comentario fue la gota que colmó el vaso. Respeto el trabajo que hacen los moderadores y es mejor dejarlos tranquilos ya que no sabes con cuantos usuarios, bots, publicaciones han lidiado.

**Otro punto de vista**

Me extraña que nadie diga nada del comentario de Francisco Nuñes, yo noto que el esta yendo en contra del trabajo de los moderadores y para mí la crítica es evidente:

> [...] dudo que algún MOD le vaya a prestar la atención que se merece

Para mí eso es criticar el trabajo de un moderador, los moderadores siempre intervienen en el sitio, unos más que otros y criticar su duro trabajo es una falta de respeto. El [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) claramente dice que se debe de evitar el sarcasmo:

> Evita el sarcasmo y ten cuidado con las bromas - el tono es difícil de descifrar en línea.[...]

Si nos ponemos a averiguar quien ofendió primero a quien entonces para mí fue primero Francisco.

**Acciones**

Si tu crees que la acción de gbianchi no fue correcta tomando todo lo hablado aquí entonces puedes emitir un reporte.

Para mí gbianchi no debe ser destituido del cargo de moderador si es lo que tienes en mente. Él no ha cometido ningún abuso de poder, ni está holgazaneando, él es bastante activo y no por nada es el mod favorito de muchos. La actitud de gbianchi no ha sido la correcta pero no olvidemos que en el sitio existen miles de usuarios y talvez algunos tampoco estén respetando el código de conducta. Lo que si podría considerar apropiado es que, si gbianchi ha tenido un comportamiento poco prudente estos últimos días, se le de una pequeña sanción por haber roto el código de conducta ya varias veces. Un pequeño descanso de unos días para pasar tiempo con la familia no viene mal :D

Comment: 1. Exacto, ese es mi posición. La destitución es una decisión muy fuerte que yo nunca pedí. No sé qué tipo de sanción merezca pero al menos yo no miraré de lado a ese tipo de acciones. 2. Para mi las acciones(por ejemplo ser rudo) de otros no me da licencia de yo hacerlas. En un grupo donde el respeto es la base no se sigue la regla de *ojo por ojo, diente por diente*.

Comment: 3. Las salas de chats suelen ser sitios más relajados donde se puede discutir de todo pero estan tambien bajo el código de conducta.  4. Por otro lado la frase argentina que señalas tiene el mismo sentido peyorativo en cualquier país hispano-hablante. Asi que para mí mandar a "callar la boca" si tiene rudeza, no es vulgar pero sí ruda. 5. Parece que muchos justifican la rudeza de un usuario por la acción de otro y la rudeza es injustificable en SO. Siento que esto último me hace pensar de forma diferente de SOes.

Comment: Es cierto que he notado que en SO el respeto es algo característico, pero como digo, esto no es pan de cada día. Puede que una u otra vez alguien pierda la cordura y actué mal, en estos casos los moderadores eliminan el comentario/publicación que infrinja el código de conducta. En este caso gbianchi ha eliminado su comentario, pero aún falta una disculpa :D. Somos una comunidad y debemos estar abiertos a todo y solucionar los problemas que se presentan, de esta forma mantendremos la calidad del sitio

Comment: No sé si el ha eliminado pero yo levante una bandera para removerlo. La cuestion es que para mí es una acciòn habitual de gbianchi que esta siendo tolerada por sus otras acciones, y para mi en ningun caso debe ser habitual. Aun si la acción fuese de John Skeet yo la señalaría. La rudeza no debe ser normalizada.

Comment: En eso estoy de acuerdo, y por eso digo que si gbianchi ha tenido estas acciones últimamente entonces debe de tomarse en serio el caso. Puede que últimamente este perdiendo la paciencia muy rápido o que tenga algunos problemas personales, entonces debería de tomarse un descanso.

Answer (score -4):

Dado la respuesta de Mauricio Contreras debo responder a sus acusaciones:

1. Yo muchas veces he querido *mandar a volar* a muchos otros usuarios por acciones como insultos, falsas acusaciones, etc. pero siempre recuerdo que en SO es un entorno donde se espera un trato respetuoso (no amical, no personal) por lo que en esos momentos ya no respondo y sigo mi camino. Lo hago porque yo pienso que SO no es un lugar como Twitter o FB donde se acepta el insulto o el trato rudo, por lo cual me siento muy orgulloso de pertenecer a un sitio como este.
2. Yo no estoy agazapado buscando errores, suelo revisar las publicaciones de  meta observando este tipo de actitudes durante mucho tiempo señalando varias veces que es incorrecto, y siempre se vuelve a lo mismo por lo que esta vez no quise quedarme con las manos atadas ya que es una actitud tóxica para el sitio (en mi opinión). Asi que quise discutir este tema en meta, un lugar para discutir este tipo de temas.
3. Los comentarios rudos los espero de usuarios nuevos que no conocen la mística de SO, o de usuarios experimentados que ya no aceptan ninguna críticas ya que en tiempos antiguos la dinámica del sitio era diferente(al menos en SOen) pero no de un moderador. Un moderador siempre fue para mi un ejemplo ya que siempre ví como corregian este tipo de acciones con paciencia, paciencia que me sirve de ejemplo.
4. Aqui no hay nada personal, yo solo veo una actitud negativa de un usuario que en la práctica es un juez de las disputas que existen en SO por ello tome la decisión de publicarlo. Si fuese otro tipo de usuario no lo hubiera hecho.
5. Más poder implica más responsabilidad, por ello yo espero más de un moderador(quizas ese sea mi error). Admiro la actividad de los moderadores ya que conociendome yo no lo podría hacer: Tomarse el tiempo de revisar los reportes, dirimir las discusiones, etc. Así que para mi los moderadores deben ser un ejemplo.
6. Mi intención nunca fue *dar porras a diestra y siniestra*. Ni armar *comidillas*. Pensé que se podría discutir sobre este tipo de actitudes en meta. Quizas estoy equivocado.
7. La discusión que señalas en el post la tome de la mejor forma, le señale de forma directa y respetuosa mi posición, él me señalo que estaba equivocado y yo seguí mi camino. Eso no tiene nada que ver con mi actual post donde la actitud ruda es evidente y no hay necesidad de preguntar, mandar a "cerrar la boca" siempre es una actitud ruda, que es muy diferente a "Da igual" o "Me vale". Por favor no equipares ya que en este caso la situación es evidente.
8. Yo no he pedido una suspensión.
9. Por último yo busco en este foro tener discusiones respetuosas, y los usuarios que guian a la comunidad(los moderadores y usuarios experimentados) deben ser un ejemplo de ello. Por ello desde que me considero un usuario experimentado siempre tengo en mente que soy un ejemplo:

   - Publicando la mejor respuesta posible que puedo hacer para la comunidad, no solo responder la pregunta del AP.
   - Comentar de forma precisa y de manera respetuosa mis inquietudes.
   - Evitar discusiones inservibles(discusiones personales, sobre DV, etc).
   - Votar por cerrar/eliminar publicaciones despues de meditar si la publicación lo merece.

   Y eso lo espero de los demás usuarios. Dado que parece que en SOes no parece cumplir con lo que yo esperaba entonces seguire mi camino, adios.

Comment: Hasta ahora sigo sin ver parecido entre SO y Twitter o FB, los comentarios denigrantes o que faltan el respeto no son pan de cada día como en las otras redes sociales. También opino que la diferencia en el significado de las palabras puede jugar un poco en contra y no ha sido la primera vez que lo he notado.

Comment: Para ser sincero creo que el usuario sí se merecía un poco el "comentario rudo", si entras al chat puedes ver las lindas "discusiones" entre Francisco Nuñes y otros usuarios y más de una vez me han dicho no estaban peleando. Tal vez tu error sea ver a los moderadores como un ejemplo, seres perfectos e inequívocos que siempre harán lo correcto, pero no es así, todos podemos cometer errores y los moderadores no están absueltos de esto y si algo pasa entonces házselo saber, creo que eso le ayudará más antes que una crítica a su trabajo :D

Comment: @Christian Puedo estar de acuerdo en muchos de tus puntos pero en uno claramente no: Nadie merece un trato rudo en SO como señala el código de conducta. Siempre hay formas de señalar de forma respetuosa su posición, y si no lo hay entonces es mejor no responder y seguir su camino. Justamente aceptar el trato rudo(que parece que muchos usuarios toleran y justifican) son un punto de inicio. Uno de mis motivos de porque me agrada SO respecto a otros foros es el respeto y eso no lo canjeo por nada. No sirve de nada saber mucho sino se tiene como base el respeto.

Answer (score -5):

[image: yo opino:]