# abuso de posición por moderador

Tags: discusión

Quiero informar a este moderador @gbianchi; está abusando de su posición.
En repetidas ocasiones es grosero, rudo y boicotea las publicaciones:

[¿Es adecuado este tipo de comentarios de un usuario, y más si es un moderador?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5235/46896)

Otros usuarios ya se han quejado de esta situación, pero ningún MOD o CM ha hecho nada para evitar el abuso.

***¡Si le escribes como el lo hace, es Incorrecto!***
***¡Pero el si puede!***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

===============================================

**Reclama respeto pero no lo da:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mensaje Borrado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

===============================================

**Otras evidencias**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El moderador gbianchi está haciendo su trabajo como le corresponde.
Otra cosa es que tú tengas algo personal contra él e interpretes cualquier comentario que hace contra ti para ningunearle y hacer posts como este o el otro que como pudiste comprobar, no fue bien aceptado.

Comment: "_¡Si le escribes como el lo hace, es Incorrecto! ¡Pero el si puede!_" Eso no es verdad. Los moderadores no estamos por encima de las normas del sitio. De hecho, los reportes que se hacen sobre un moderador los revisa un moderador diferente para ser neutrales. En concreto, en el caso del primer comentario que pusiste, éste fue revisado y eliminado por otro moderador (yo), como se revisaría y eliminaría un comentario similar hecho por otro usuario. Después lo hablamos en la sala de chat entre todos los moderadores.

Comment: Coge cada uno de los elementos por sí solos y verás que ninguno tiene entidad como abuso. La suma de ellos, tampoco. No entro en el chat, pero de vez en cuando miro las transcripciones. En ellas me da la sensación de que actúas algo revolucionado. Tal vez sea el momento de parar un poco, coger distancia, reflexionar sobre la comunidad, leer sus líneas maestras y replantear tu uso de ella. Puedes aportar cosas valiosísimas, pero debes querer. Si lo conviertes en una batalla, no creo que acabe bien: debes saber que el bien de la comunidad prevalece sobre el ego de uno.

Comment: Álvaro y fedorqui: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5245/abuso-de-posici%c3%b3n-por-moderador#comment22808_5248

Comment: vean la respuestas y comentario de @Israel-ICM, saludos

Comment: No veo nada malo en el comentario agregado en "otras evidencias". Suponiendo que lo que dijo Gbianchi es malo (cosa en la que no quiero profundizar), quizá solo explotó y ya. Que pierda la paciencia una vez y diga algo malo por eso para mi es perdonable. IMHO deberías agregar más evidencia fuerte de que Gbianchi está siendo grosero con alguien.

Comment: @DanteS. la mejor evidencia es que si otro usuario usa las misma palabras que Gbianchi usa es baneado ...

Comment: Si eso es cierto, es un abuso de poder para mi. Sin embargo, eso no prueba que Gbianchi tenga malas intenciones realmente.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso tienes pruebas de esa frase ?? "usuario baneado por decir lo mismo que gbianchi" ?? Y el abuso de poder seria que el mismo gbianchi lo banee no ???

Comment: @Excorpion están en los post y esa no es la única forma de abuso ... otra cosa el post dice posición no poder son dos cosas distintas... que no quieren terminar de entender...

Comment: Pero en ningun lado aparece que fue gbianchi el que lo hizo

Comment: @Excorpion mmm como que no lo dice... https://i.imgur.com/5VbShOS.png te hacesss....

Comment: Eso es un comentario, no es una confirmacion de que el tuyo fue borrado por el

Comment: @Excorpion te perdiste... no voy a explicarte mas nada, estas divagando .... y haciendo juegos de palabras no se que ganas con eso ... eso es boicotear a una persona ... comentas cosas sin sentido ...

Comment: @Excorpion ***Boicotear:** Impedir o interrumpir el desarrollo normal de un proceso o de un acto como medida de protesta o como medio de presión para conseguir algo.*

Comment: Meh, ahora todos te atacan, estoy preguntando algo puntual que dices, `Y el abuso de poder seria que el mismo gbianchi lo banee no ???` a lo que me respondes con `están en los post` y no lo veo en que momento el haya borrado algo. Eso fue claramente lo que pregunte. Pero no, estas todo ofuscado y poniendo a quien sea en tu contra.

Comment: respuesta *me parece que no la leíste*: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5245/abuso-de-posici%c3%b3n-por-moderador?noredirect=1#comment22844_5245

Comment: Me pones que no leo EXACTAMENTE LA MISMA FRASE QUE TE PONGO QUE SI LEI !?!?!?!? Literal, tu comentario esta en cuando dije """"a lo que me respondes con""" es exactamente el mismo comentario que linkeas, wtf

Comment: @Excorpion eres tu el que esta hablando de abuso de poder, todos han usado esa palabra para boicotear el post cuando yo en ningún momento la he usado... busca en mi post cuando he dicho algo sobre abuso de poder...

Comment: Abuso de poder es cuando alguien usa ***sus privilegios (poniéndole un nombre)*** para hacer algo y retorcer las cosas a su favor; el abuso de posición es cuando alguien usa su posición para evadir y retorcer las normas (no necesita actuar por si mismo).

Comment: @Excorpion pero dl sigan retorciendo el post....

Comment: No veo la diferencia, pero bueno, para ti lo hay... posición en esta caso es lo mismo que poder, por que el es un moderador, nosotros no. Muchos de nosotros estamos de acuerdo con lo que dices, sobre las actitudes rudas de gbianchi, pero a la mayoria no le importa, por que el rol de moderador no se vee afectado o eso creen varios. Sigo diciendo, tu post da a entender que gbianchi fue el que borro cosas, eso es abuso de poder, eso es lo que estaba buscando...

Comment: De todos modos, dices que igual retuerzo las cosas al no entenderlas como exactamente tu quieres, por lo que dejare de comentar este tema desde ahora en adelante y los que vengan con respecto a ello... ya que no quieres comentarios como los mios en el.

Comment: Como dije en mi respuesta, para mi abuso de poder y abuso de posicion es lo mismo. Pues si puedes abusar de la posición, es por que esa posición tiene poder.

Comment: @DanteS. no es así ... si fuera así todos los políticos corruptos estuvieran presos... los políticos abusan de su posición para obtener algo, incluso para joder a alguien que les cae mal sin verse involucrados, pero voz no estas preparado para esa conversación ... es como cuando una mujer usa su genero para obtener beneficios, hizo algo no ...

Comment: te explico lo siguiente: cualquier usuario que trate a otro usuario como lo hace gbianchi; será amonestado, baneado por muy pendeja que sea la situación. ha pero si lo hace el sr moderador le dan Like ... Si un usuario cualquiera defiende a un moderador le llueven los likes aunque lo que haya dicho vaya en contra de las normas del sitio ... y los moderadores no hacen nada ...

Comment: No, por que el politico puede abusar de su poder para que no esté preso. Eso ultimo de la mujer es cierto, pero de cierto modo el genero femenino tiene PODER para reclamar.

Comment: Tienes pruebas de esa lluvia de likes? o esos likes a favor del moderador? O al menos una anegdota de una vez que haya sucedido (sin tener en cuenta esta pregunta en meta)

Comment: Haces acusaciones, pero tienes poca evidencia que pruebe que tus acusaciones son ciertas. Sin embargo, no hablo lo suficiente con Gbianchi como para conocer bien su actitud. Por esa razón no vote ni a favor ni en contra. Para estar de acuerdo contigo, necesitaria evidencia que pruebe que tus acusaciones son ciertas y que Gbianchi tenga una actitud agresiva todo el tiempo (con uno o mas usuarios). Por eso, yo no apoyo ni estoy en contra de las acusaciones.

Comment: @DanteS. un CM borro el comentario del chat, por que lo contacte, ya que los MODS no hicieron nada  ... por eso ya no aparece con estrellas (Likes); pero mira esta actitud de un usuario apadrinados por los MODS, es correcto burlarse de los demás, pregunta si le hicieron algo al usuario, de las mismas actitudes me vengo quejando yo y otro usuario [Link](https://i.imgur.com/9fWUnpv.png)

Comment: y lo mismo pasa con la forma en que contesta gbianchi ... pero no quieren ver lo que no les importa... como dice @Excorpion no tiene importancia... para los demás ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent en lo que se refiere al comentario del chat, la acusacion es infundada. El comentario al que haces referencia lo eliminé yo, no un CM. De verdad te pediría que reflexiones y tratemos entre todos de bajar esta tensión que no ayuda en nada al sitio ni a ninguno de nosotros. Todos podemos equivocarnos, incluidos tu o nosotros los moderadores.

Comment: @Pikoh sugiero lo mismo a los contribuyentes de la comunidad... yo solo he respondido a las preguntas que me hacen... y a las aclaraciones necesarias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmmm seré lo más neutral posible en este caso, no quiero juzgar ni nada de eso porque no me corresponde.

Veo que este problema que bajo mi perspectiva se está haciendo "*personal*" se está extendiendo demasiado, no soy alguien que pasa horas en el chat creo que ni siquiera minutos pero por las acciones que veo creo poco a poco este problema va de mal en peor, **¿Por qué no aclarar de una vez este asunto y darle fin?**, no puedo respaldar a ninguno de los bandos ya que nunca he tenido una relación cercana ni siquiera un saludo con los afectados en este caso, tampoco soy fan de ninguno así que no tendré preferencia o inclinación hacia alguno.

Verdaderamente por mas que intento no veo tal boicot que se menciona, entiendo también el problema que bastantes días de debate ha levantado, me refiero a la publicación **[¿Es adecuado este tipo de comentarios de un usuario, y más si es un moderador?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5235/es-adecuado-este-tipo-de-comentarios-de-un-usuario-y-m%c3%a1s-si-es-un-moderador)**, esto se hubiera evitado si ambos hubieran guardado sus impulsos tanto como el usuario [@FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/46896/francisco-n%c3%ba%c3%b1ez-todo-poderoso) con su comentario ***"dudo que algún MOD le vaya a prestar la atención que se merece"*** como el comentario del moderador [@gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) que ya todos conocen y también se agrega en la pregunta, en cuanto a la ultima captura del comentario de @gbianchi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***"no.. no hay nada de malo.. llamalo como quieras"*** pues no veo tal agresión, es mi opinión, o tal vez sea que en mi país somos mas agresivos en la forma de hablar o no se, pero no le encuentro lo agresivo (recalco es mi opinión, tal vez otra persona si lo vería ofensivo).

Dicho esto creo que debería ya pasarse página y dejar de echar leña al fuego, ambos tuvieron ese momento de arranque pero **¿Para qué seguir subiendo publicaciones en meta sobre este caso?** entiendo también que lo que se quiere es "*justicia*" o al menos eso veo, pero en este caso hay bastantes posiciones y encontrar "*justicia*" será muy complicado porque varios usuarios según veo consideramos que la agresión fue de ambas partes y no solo de una.

Para terminar, [@FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/46896/francisco-n%c3%ba%c3%b1ez-todo-poderoso) no lo tomes muy personal, ese comentario en tu respuesta podría haberla realizado cualquier revisor, pero lo hizo @gbianchi, tranquilo "Solo es un comentario", otra cosa sería tener todos los `-1` que recibió el usuario @Hackerman en sus preguntas eso si sería un problema personal y boicot según yo.

Es mi opinión totalmente neutral como dije antes, si alguien debe pedir disculpas creo que son ambos y aceptar sus culpas como dos personas maduras y profesionales que son.

Comment: aquí el tema es el siguiente:
***primer punto:***
un usuario hace un post: cualquier participación mía que sea detectada por un grupo de personas.
apuesto que los votos negativos que recibo son del mismo grupo de personas.

Comment: incluso he creado post elavorados que en menos de 15 segundos ya tienen votos negativos, esto solo es un ejemplo... 
mi opinion con los votos negativos es que no tinen sentido si no van junto a un buen comentario...
aquellos que dejan un voto negativo sin comentario son el equivalente a los que no votan en las eleccions n su pais.

Comment: ***segundo punto:***
buco el apoyo en gbianchi por que el sabe de base de datos no por que me caiga bien o por que sea MOD. pero tambien creo que por ser profesional dara un trato como tal...
el tema es que simpre que busco su ayuda me sale con comntarios tan generales que no se a que se refire... y al poco rato caen 3-4 votos negativos y estoy seguro que son del mismo grupo de personas que en ese preciso momento see conctan...

Comment: ***tercer punto y el por que del post:*** si bien yo he sido rudo con el... es por que el me ha tratado asi ... ha pero con resultados diferentes... 

en resumen no tiene importancia por que solo es un par de usuarios afectados.

Comment: pero si ubiera plata de por medio... stoy seguro que tanto el trato como la atencion seria diferentes...

Comment: mira como me responde el sr: [Link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59192143#59192143) principalmente aquí: https://i.imgur.com/uJCqOmP.png

Comment: pero bueno todo el mundo esta de acuerdo en que el hace lo correcto; este post trata de denunciar lo contrario...

Comment: @Francisco Núñez-Todo Poderoso, exacto como bien dices *"no hay plata de por medio"* todos incluso tú estas aquí por que te nace simplemente por eso, así como cuando vemos una pregunta y a veces no nos nace responder o simplemente somos selectivos con a quien respondemos, no todos los usuarios en SOes tenemos que ser amigos, ahora si hay un grupo en contra tuya la denuncia que haces sería contra todo el grupo y no así solo con gbianchi

Comment: La cosa es simplemente que si seguimos con acusaciones que a mi parecer no llegaran a nada e irán empeorando con el tiempo y aunque se destituya al moderador el grupo que entre comillas "te boicotea" seguirá haciendolo de igual forma

Comment: Como bien digo en mi respuesta lo mejor es ya pasar pagina y que las cosas sigan su curso hasta que otro moderador o un CM se encargue del asunto, la idea es simplemente convivir entre usuarios sean o no moderadores

Comment: El problema es que la evidencia que presentas es muy subjetiva, ya que cada uno lo ve de diferente forma, es muy complicado para mi decir que tienes la razón porque mi postura me dice que ambos son los agredidos y los agresores

Comment: al primer comentario: nada de eso justifica un trato rudo ... y es correcto, este post es lo que se sugiere haca: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges

Comment: de mi parte yo siento que lo he tratado igual como el me ha tratado a mi incluso he tratado de aclarar alguna diferencias en donde el es rudo... y esta frase s la que ínsita a esos problemas: ***piensa lo que quieras***, ***has lo que quieras*** .... esto aunque no use mala palabras son groserías.

Comment: yo respeto tu opinión... pero no la comparto...

Answer (score 12):

La pregunta era de baja calidad, la respuesta hace piggy backing en las otras respuestas y no responde a la pregunta, por lo que a nadie en el futuro le va a servir. Es decir, lo mismo que te comenté en tu pregunta. Es decir, estoy de acuerdo con lo que comentó en el chat y, además, no mencionó tu boca ni te dijo nada sobre ti, sólo opinó sobre tu pregunta.

Hablar de las preguntas ajenas no tiene nada que ver con hablar de los demás o caer en falacias *ad hominem*. Eso hace débil la conexión que argumentas entre un tema tratado en otro hilo y lo que sucedió el día de hoy.

Como comentaron en el otro hilo, el camino es hablar con otro moderador y no abrir un hilo como este.

Comment: el post no es sobre mi POST en SOes... es sobre los comentario y las acciones del moderador.

Comment: y es lo que se indica aquí: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso estás diciendo tú mismo que te boicotea. Eso es en las preguntas que tú mismo estás citando en este post. Estás negando lo que dices aquí mismo. Ya expresé mi opinión al respecto, supongo que otros tendrán otras opiniones.

Comment: no es solamente eso es en general... pero dale entiendo que lo defiendas.. como tu mismo lo dices es tu mentor...

Comment: asumo que estas de acuerdo en que sus comentarios sean rudos... pero si alguien le contesta igual es Crimen de lesa humanidad.

Comment: Cada vez comenta una publicación su comentario no aporta nada... y lo que dijo en el chat demuestra que ni siquiera había leído la pregunta... y tal como le contesta a otros usuarios yo le conteste en l chat... en ningún momento fui grosero incluso le puse la imagen de lo que no había leído.

Answer (score 7):

Estaré al ojo, yo los estaba leyendo y era una conversación típica entre uds.
Pero acá estás desarrollando dos cosas...
1- Supuesto abuso de poder de Moderador
2- "..es grosero, rudo..." 
3- "..boicotea las publicaciones.."

Si abusa de la Moderación es una cosa (Una grave en caso de ser cierta, pero lo dudo)
Que sea pesado, rudo, es otra y no tiene que ver con lo anterior
Pero el último punto me desconcierta, por que no veo pruebas de eso, boicot como tal no hay, a menos que me señales algo que no haya visto o que yo no considere como boicot.

En el chat hasta nos enteramos que te paso, y por que te sancionaron, pero asumiste por rapidez que el actor de los hechos fue bianchi, lo que es un error fatal solo por que tienes la cabeza caliente en ese momento.
Lo correcto hubiese sido esperar a que pase la sanción, que es corta, y preguntar luego que sucedió, si te cae sanción debe ser por algo, y no hay que adelantarse a los hechos.

Por último y tiene que ver con las imágenes, en esta y la publicación enlazada. Todas están sacadas de contexto, o bordando el fuera de contexto, por que tergiversar el real hecho es mucho más sencillo.
Está el ejemplo del "cállate la boca" donde da una clara explicación, pero no hay pruebas de lo que sucedió antes, que al menos yo si se que ocurrió y por que desenlazó así.

Ahora a esperar el desarrollo no más, no veo que vayas a lograr nada con un ataque desesperado y calentado de cabeza. Es un ataque abierto y sin bases, y con acusaciones fuertes entre medio.

Comment: Cada vez comenta una publicación su comentario no aporta nada... y lo que dijo en el chat demuestra que ni siquiera había leído la pregunta (genera una mala percepción de mis preguntas) por que no es mas directo y dice algo como: ***te faltan datos de ejemplo***, ***puedes dar una mejor explicación*** ... y tal como le contesta a otros usuarios yo le conteste en el chat... en ningún momento fui grosero incluso le puse la imagen de lo que no había leído.

Comment: viste el comentario??? imagen #2 marcado en rojo.

Comment: no es un tema de emociones... es las palabras que usa y las acciones que se toman... si le digo que esta ciego porque no lee o no ve el POST.... es el toma represarías basadas en mociones..

Comment: Si un comentario no aporta nada, se ignora, por eso son comentarios y no respuestas. Las respuestas son las que le importan al OP más que nada y no le interesará que gbianchi diga que eso no es respuesta si al OP le sirve. Y si, lo del chat, es parte del chat, lo cual no va a tus 3 puntos debatidos acá.

Comment: Si la palabras que usa están mal por reglas, se reportan. Si las acciones están mal por regla, es el mismo caso.

Comment: los comentarios influyen en las publicaciones ... de no ser así no existirán

Comment: tengo respuestas aceptadas por el OP con -2 de puntuación. Si te interesa una puntuación por sobre lo que le sirve en el momento al OP, estás enfocándote mal.

Comment: no me refiero a la puntuación cuando tu entras y vez una publicación donde un MOD se expresa como lo  hizo el, tu respuesta o forma en que vayas a ayudar se varia afectada contextualmente... asumiendo que es un MOD y que su opinión tiene importancia... pero no se diga mas ... tienes toda la razón... el todo lo hace bien.. bye ...

Comment: Contextualmente vale lo mismo. Boicotear una respuesta es hecharla a perder en su totalidad, cosa que no sucede. El abuso y el boicot seria si el mod fuese borrandote, cerrandote, etc, cosas por ahi a lo loco sin respaldo en las reglas.

Comment: Y no, nunca he dicho que el hace todo bien, ni siquiera dije algo similar a eso.

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la primera vez que decido dejar mi granito de arena en una discusión en meta (sin contar mis comentarios).

---

Te doy mi opinion. No soy usuario frecuente del chat (aunque lo era). Sin embargo las veces en las que tuve una oportunidad de hablar con Gbianchi, me pareció una persona no agresiva. Incluso me tuvo paciencia a mi que no cumpli con su pedido al haber hecho [esta pregunta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5254/estamos-yendo-demasiado-lejos-con-evitar-el-spam-de-como-programar-una-secuenci) y a pesar de eso se tomo el tiempo, paciencia y energía de atender mi critica.

No conozco bien el contexto de sus mensajes quizá agresivos, pero suponiendo que Gbianchi haya dicho algo malo (de lo cual profundizaré mas tarde), es normal que una persona explote a veces. Y si un moderador (o cualquier usuario) explotase por que ha estado en una discusión difícil que requiere mucha paciencia, yo lo perdonaría. A cualquiera nos puede pasar.

A continuación, daré mi opinion sobre las evidencias que muestras sobre el comportamiento de Gbianchi.

#### evidencia 1: "seria interesante que cerraras un poquito la boca"

Para mi ahí Gbianchi se pasó un poco. Sin embargo, al desconocer el contexto del comentario (el cual pido que agregues en la pregunta si es posible), su comentario podría ser resultado de perder un poquito la paciencia contigo.

#### "Pide respeto pero no lo da"

Estuve leyendo el chat, y no encontré mucha información con respecto a esta. Lo que le dijiste a Gbianchi antes de que te pidiera respeto, pareció que rezongabas, lo cual es una actitud que puede verse algo agresiva, aunque esa no sea tu intención. Quizá por eso te pidió respeto. La verdad no logro formar una opinion fuerte de esta.

#### Evidencia 2: "llamalo como quieras"

Yo tampoco veo el "llamalo como quieras" como agresivo.

---

Conclusión: Solo vi un poco de agresividad por parte de Gbianchi en una de las dos evidencias. Yo creo que a tu aviso de abuso de posicion le faltan dos cosas:

- Dar información (al menos links) sobre el contexto, ya que no todos estamos informados totalmente sobre los sucesos que describes.
- Más evidencia de que Gbianchi está siendo agresivo o abusando de su posición. Por que una cosa es que pierda un poco de paciencia una vez, otra cosa es que esté siendo agresivo con muchos sin razón aparente.

Comment: he tratado de conversar y darte una visión mas amplia del contexto en el chat y comentarios; pero seria bueno que los Moderadores o otros usuarios te den su punto de vista... ya que mi punto de vista es muy personal y a lo mejor... cuando lo veas desde un punto global pierda sentido y creas que... bah tanto escandalo por un par de usuarios... échenle cal y empújenlo para la orilla...

Comment: para un mayor contexto puedes ver los comentarios de esta respusta tambien: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5248/46896