# Estamos yendo demasiado lejos con evitar el spam de "como programar una secuencia en Python"

Tags: discusión, comunidad

Hoy apareció una pregunta llamada [Como programar una lista en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489421/c%c3%b3mo-programar-una-lista-en-python#489421) (ya está borrada). El contenido de la pregunta no tenía nada de malo, el op solo buscaba información sobre otras formas de crear una lista en python, conociendo como hacerlo.

- Si, es verdad que el OP debería haber investigado antes de preguntar, ya que en la [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) incluso se responde a su pregunta.
- Si, es verdad que se parece un poco a "como crear una secuencia en Python"(a la que me referire de ahora en adelante como la pregunta-spam)

Si bien el primer punto justificaría cerrar la pregunta debido a una falta de esfuerzo por parte del OP, no se justifica que la pregunta sea spam, ya que nadie lo publico antes y no hay manera de probar que dicha pregunta se relaciona con la pregunta-spam.

Sin embargo, el primer comentario fue "voto por cerrar esta pregunta por ser SPAM". Luego de un rato, la pregunta fue cerrada. Y luego eliminada (por cierto mientras intentaba dar una respuesta en los comentarios).

Acaso ahora todas las preguntas que sean sobre secuencias en Python son consideradas spam por la comunidad y borradas por un moderador? Eso no limita injustamente el tipo de preguntas que se pueden hacer en SO es?

(ya vengo venir a la respuesta diciendo "Si" a la primera pregunta xD)

NO digo que la pregunta-spam deba ser mas aceptada, si no que no llevemos demasiado lejos esto de evitar el spam en el sitio.

Comment: Empezar con esa frase, aunque sea cierta, no es la manera de estar seguro de la publicación continuaré leyendo, pero te recomiendo tener más seguridad y confianza en tus dichos. Si fuese por que siempre estamos todos de acuerdo, no existirían las discusiones, cosa que es el punto de meta en este caso.

Comment: Tienes razon, mejor lo quito, pero aun pienso que no será tan bien recibida.

Comment: El problema de las preguntas de baja calidad es que acaban cerradas/eliminadas y acaban creando frustración al que responde (o intenta responder). La solución no es responder en los comentarios. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro y cual es la solución? A mi no me frustraria responder y que luego sea eliminada, mi objetivo principal es ayudar al OP. Si de paso ayudo a otros, genial! Como mucho lo que pudo causarme frustración es que sea eliminada antes de que pudiera responder, pero nada mas. De cualquier modo me quejaba más en nombre del OP.

Comment: La solución es votar por cerrar la pregunta. Responder a una pregunta de baja calidad puede ayudar a ese usuario puntualmente pero daña a la comunidad en general (y por ende al resto de usuarios, presentes y futuros) porque se está promocionando contenido de baja calidad. Y responder en los comentarios no es una buena opción porque los comentarios en StackOverflow no se indexan y no completan la publicación (no se pueden marcar como aceptados, por lo que la pregunta aparecería como no resuelta).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Es mas, estamos gastando votos de cierre, perdiendo tiempo y discutiendo sobre preguntas que todavía no sabemos como manejar.

La pregunta era SPAM. Cumple todos los lineamientos internos que ya sabemos para considerarla spam (que no voy a enumerar, porque en algunos casos incluye información privada).

Entrar en discusiones, solo porque parecía no ser SPAM, en lugar de dejarnos a los moderadores que tenemos mas información, tomar la decisión sobre si era o no SPAM, es una perdida de tiempo y energía entre ustedes.

Les pedí que solo las reportaran.. que no las votaran, que no entablaran discusiones, ni que hicieran nada al respecto.. solo avisan, y si veo que no es SPAM (paso con dos) las dejamos vivitas y coleando, pongo mi comentario de usuario novato, y aquí no paso nada.

Pero si es SPAM, tenemos todo un protocolo para saber como manejar los casos, y están siendo seguidos por los CM.

Comment: Pues yo no estoy de acuerdo con esos lineamientos. Entiendo que la pregunta SI merecía ser cerrada por que el OP no investigó por su cuenta, pero no eliminada. Entonces, todas las preguntas que no cumplen un lineamiento de la comunidad son spam y deben ser eliminadas?

Comment: Y si yo no estoy de acuerdo con los moderadores? Y que hago yo si veo que medio mundo las reportan como spam? Como hago un reporte que diga "No es spam" sin malgastar el tiempo de ustedes usando mal un recurso del sitio?

Comment: Entonces, yo debo quedarme de brazos cruzados, mientras no puedo ni dejar un comentario a aquella persona que necesita ayuda? Este es un sitio que debería ser para apoyar a todos los que podamos.

Comment: @DanteS. las preguntas cerradas con votos negativos y ninguna respuesta positiva son eliminadas automáticamente por el sistema pasados X días. La pregunta iba a ser eliminada de todos modos, por lo que respondiendo a la pregunta del primer comentario: Sí, las preguntas que no cumplen con el lineamiento de la comunidad (sean o no spam) son eliminadas.

Comment: @DanteS. Si no estás de acuerdo con la decisión tomada por alguno de los moderadores, puedes optar por varias posibilidades: 1. Reportar la publicación para que la revisen los otros moderadores. 2. Reportar la publicación para que la revisen los administradores de la comunidad. 3. Escribir sobre el tema en meta. Has creado una pregunta en meta y viendo los votos parece que la comunidad no ve el problema de la misma manera (recuerda que funcionan de manera diferente en meta).

Comment: @DanteS. Aunque la pregunta en cuestión no es spam en sí, esa no es la razón por la que fue cerrada. La publicación no se ajusta al contenido y formato del sitio y tenía varios reportes de baja calidad (entre ellos uno del propio sistema automático del sitio.) Al cerrarse la pregunta, un comentario con los motivos y enlaces al centro de ayuda con detalles se añade al principio, y la persona que creó la pregunta puede verlo (aunque sea eliminada). Eso ayudará al usuario/a a crear una publicación mejor que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Me convenciste. aunque no se como hacer el reporte. Si lo pones como una respuesta te lo acepto c:

Comment: @DanteS. Si quieres contactar con los moderadores: dale al enlace de "reportar" al pie de la pregunta y elige "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" donde podrás escribir el mensaje. Y éste es el [enlace de contacto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) por si quieres contactar con el equipo de la comunidad (y no con los moderadores). Mi opinión como moderador y usuario, es que no creo que tengas un caso sólido y lo más seguro es que el equipo de la comunidad te refiera de vuelta a aquí (meta de esSO). Pero eso no quiere decir que no los contactes.

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir. No es un usuario real. No es un usuario que quiere aprender ni que quiera usar el sitio. No entiendo que necesitas que te expliquemos. Podrias especificar pq merece nuestro tiempo una pregunta que no es real?

Comment: @gbianchi Mi objetivo es ayudar desinteresadamente a todos. Sobre que explicar, ya deje mi opinion, Alvaro Montoro dijo algo clave (la pregunta no fue cerrada ni eliminada por spam, si no por que no cumple los lineamientos de la comunidad). En conclusion, ya no hay nada que explicar. Es que no es una pregunta del todo, es mas una critica y opinion.

Comment: @alvaromontoro gracias por el link c: pero ya esta resuelto (lee el comentario que le deje a Gbianchi) ademas, empece a pensar que seguir con esto no valia la pena.

Comment: Quieres una explicacion de por que merece el tiempo? Por que toda persona merece ser ayudada. Esta publicacion no fue por mi, fue en nombre de todos los futuros OP que pregunten en so es. Quiero que los reciba una comunidad dispuesta a resolver sus dudas (siempre que se sigan los lineamientos), no una que los considere sus publicaciones spam por que "es de los creadores de como crear una secuencia en python".

Comment: Pero la comunidad si ayuda y enseña a usar el sitio... El problema con estas preguntas es que no son reales. Los usuarios, puede que sean reales. Pero no estan viniendo al sitio a aprender, estan viniendo al sitio a cumplir un ejercicio que les dio un profesor. Hay aproximadamente 50 preguntas borradas en los ultimos dias con variaciones sobre el mismo tema. Y cuando esto empezo, hace 1 año, hicimos todos los esfuerzos por comunicarnos con estos usuarios. y absolutamente ninguno contesto nada. Esto no es una pregunta en particular, esto es lo que estamos trabajando para erradicar...

Comment: @gbianchi perdón, no me había fijado de que era una de esas cuentas :S

Comment: Es mas, el usuario creo la pregunta, e inmediatamente se dio de baja... que es algo nuevo en nuestros registros... Pero cuando digo inmediatamente, fue al minuto de crear la pregunta....

Comment: es mas.. dicho usuario escribio luego en su pregunta... "Es para una tarea, lo siento"... necesitas mas informacion sobre que no era una pregunta real? la tarea es escribir una pregunta en el sitio (y uno de los ejemplos de que escribir, es esto que viste)

Comment: Ya veo. Tienes razon con que no es una pregunta real, es mas, parece que hay un profesor vago dando esas tareas. Me convenciste de que no hemos llegado demasiado lejos, pero si llego a ver un caso donde si lleguemos demasiado lejos, volvere aqui en meta.

Answer (score 3):

> El contenido de la pregunta no tenía nada de malo

La pregunta carece del conocimiento básico para siquiera formularla.

Decir que "no tiene nada de malo" es una falacia.

> No se justifica que la pregunta sea spam

Probablemente, la categoría a tu parecer puede estar errada, pero si no era cerrada por spam, lo era por no respetar las normas básicas de SO.

Yo estoy de acuerdo con que se haya cerrado, ya sea por spam, o baja calidad. Ahora, al parecer terminó eliminada por spam, no estoy seguro de esto ultimo.

> ¿Acaso ahora todas las preguntas que sean sobre secuencias en Python son consideradas spam por la comunidad y borradas por un moderador?

No, si siguen los lineamientos básicos no debería haber problema.
Ahora, las cosas no son cerradas "por un moderador" es un grupo de personas que esta de acuerdo con el cierre de esta. Y el cierre no es el fin de la pregunta, significa que debe ser reformulada para que sea aceptada.

No creo que se haya ido lejos al cerrar la pregunta, como dije, debe ser reformulada, demostrar un intento básico o conocimiento básico de python.

Por que como dije en la pregunta, acá no se enseña a programar, se resuelven problemas de programación, cosa que la pregunta "como programar una secuencia en Python" no lo es.

Comment: El problema no es que se haya cerrado, yo también estoy de acuerdo con el cierre. El problema es el motivo del cierre y que probablemente fue borrada por spam, quitandole la oportunidad al OP de reformularla, de repensarla o incluso casi perdió la oportunidad de que lo guiase para que investigue.

Comment: Ese sistema de cerrar las preguntas lo entiendo, se que no es por un moderador. Pero solo un moderador (y en algunos casos el usuario que escribio la pregunta) puede eliminar una pregunta. Lo que fue demasiado lejos para mi fue borrarla "por spam", no cerrarla como tal.

Comment: Pensandolo bien me pregunto si fue el propio OP el que la eliminó... Lo plantearé en el chat.